# sed regex to non-greedy replace?

Tags: regex, unix, replace, sed, garbage-collection

I am aware of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) that is quite similar, but for some reason I'm still having problems.

I have a GC log that I'm trying to *trim out* the Tenured section enclosed in `[]`.

```
63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546: [Tenured: 1416K->1065K(1536K), 0.0492621 secs] 1922K->1065K(2112K), 0.0513331 secs]
```

I apply `s/\[Tenured:.*\]//`

And quite expectantly, the result is trimmed *greedily* through the remainder of the line:

```
63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546:
```

So let's try and be non-greedy **not** match a closing right bracket with `s/\[Tenured:[^\]]*\]//` but alas no match is made and sed skips over the line, producing the same original output:

```
63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546: [Tenured: 1416K->1065K(1536K), 0.0492621 secs] 1922K->1065K(2112K), 0.0513331 secs]
```

How do I non-greedily match and replace that section?  Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost: s/\[Tenured:[^]]*\]//

The manual says:

> To include a literal ']' in the list, make it the first character
>   (following a possible '^').

i.e. No backslash is required in this context.

- Raz

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/\[Tenured:[^]]*\]//'
```

Apparently you shouldn't escape the close square bracket. Wacky!

From `man re_format`:

> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed in '[]' ...
>   **To include a literal ']' in the list, make it the first character (following a possible `^').**

Comment: Wow, that is wacky.  I knew about the `^` situation, but not the `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.*?` for the non-greedy variant of `.*`. (Not sure if it's supported in `sed`'s regex engine or not, but it's worth a try.)

Edit: This previous SO question may be relevant - [Non greedy regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: I don't believe sed supports that, but regardless I just tried it again and no joy.

Comment: See mentioned question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed

Comment: sed supports it with the -r (GNU) or -E (BSD) flags.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
echo "63.544: [GC 63.544: [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0017902 secs]63.546: [Tenured: 1416K->1065K(1536K), 0.0492621 secs] 1922K->1065K(2112K), 0.0513331 secs]" | sed -e s/\\[Tenured:[^\]]*\\]//
```

Comment: I think that works because the shell was doing the escaping prior to getting to sed.  The same would not be true unfortunately for a sed script file.