# Sed - pattern matching with binary value as separator?

Tags: sed

Is it possible to use binary values in `sed` pattern matching?

I have a one line strings which contain plain text fields separated by binary value 1 as separator.

Is it possible to use `sed` to much everything up to binary separator 1?

Or should I use `awk`?

Example string where `\x1` represents binary value 1:

```
key1=value1\x1key2=value2\x1key3=value3
```

Example expected output, values for `key1` and `key2`:

```
value1 value2
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It would be helpful to see some expected output.

Comment: I'm matching the key and outputting the value for specific key only, for example I would only want to see output "value1 value2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit**: Here are a couple of options for printing the values based on a list of keys, couldn't figure out a more concise way with `awk` but one probably exists:

```
$ echo -e 'key1=value1\001key2=value2\001key3=value3' > test

$ sed 's/\x01/\n/g' test | awk -F= '{if ($1 == "key1" || $1 == "key2") print $2}'
value1
value2

$ sed 's/\x01/\n/g' test | perl -pe 's/((key1|key2)=(.*)|.*)/\3/'
value1
value2
```

You can't match everything up to the first `\x1` since `sed` does not support non-greedy matching, your options are to use a different language, or something like the following:

```
$ sed 's/\x01/\n/g' test | head -n 1
key1=value1
```

The answer to the following question has a good example of using a Perl regex for non-greedy matches:
[Non greedy regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: correct I need non-greedy, it seems like I might get this done in C++ faster than anything else

Comment: Edited my answer with some potential solutions for what you need to do, but doing this in C++ might be preferable if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a way to get the \x1 in binary in the command there as sed doesn't parse it.  For example to convert them all to new lines:

```
sed -e "s/$(echo -e \\001)/\n/g" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Control-A</kbd> at the point where you want the character `\001` to appear.

I would find this a lot easier than handling all the necessary escaping to get `echo` to produce the correct string if there are any backslashes in the regex - and I find there often are such backslashes.