# How can I match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Take this regular expression: `/^[^abc]/`. This will match any single character at the beginning of a string, except *a*, *b*, or *c*.

If you add a `*` after it – `/^[^abc]*/` – the regular expression will continue to add each subsequent character to the result, until it meets either an `a`, **or** `b`, **or** `c`.

For example, with the source string `"qwerty qwerty whatever abc hello"`, the expression will match up to `"qwerty qwerty wh"`.

But what if I wanted the matching string to be `"qwerty qwerty whatever "`?

In other words, how can I match everything up to (but not including) the *exact sequence* `"abc"`?

Comment: What do you mean by `match but not including` ?

Comment: I mean I want to match `"qwerty qwerty whatever "` – not including the "abc". In other words, I **don't** want the resulting match to be `"qwerty qwerty whatever abc"`.

Comment: In javascript you can just `do string.split('abc')[0]`. Certainly not an official answer to this problem, but I find it more straightforward than regex.

Comment: @Toto he means like this [one](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/7016376771bf) not include abc.

Answer (score 1509, accepted):

You didn't  specify which flavor  of regex  you're using, but  this will
work in any of the most popular ones that can be considered "complete".

```
/.+?(?=abc)/
```

#### How it works

The  `.+?`  part is  the  un-greedy  version of  `.+`  (one  or more  of
anything). When we use `.+`, the engine will basically match everything.
Then, if there is  something else in the regex it will  go back in steps
trying to  match the  following part. This  is the  **greedy** behavior,
meaning **as much as possible to satisfy**.

When using  `.+?`, instead of  matching all at  once and going  back for
other conditions (if any), the engine  will match the next characters by
step until the  subsequent part of the regex is  matched (again if any).
This  is  the **un-greedy**,  meaning  match  **the fewest  possible  to
satisfy**.

```
/.+X/  ~ "abcXabcXabcX"        /.+/  ~ "abcXabcXabcX"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/.+?X/ ~ "abcXabcXabcX"        /.+?/ ~ "abcXabcXabcX"
          ^^^^                          ^
```

Following  that   we  have   `(?=`**`{contents}`**`)`,  a   *zero  width
assertion*,  a  *look around*.  This  grouped  construction matches  its
contents, but does not count  as characters matched (**zero width**). It
only returns if it is a match or not (**assertion**).

Thus, in other terms the regex `/.+?(?=abc)/` means:

> Match any  characters as  few  as possible  until a  "abc" is  found,
>   without counting the "abc".

Comment: This will probably not work with line breaks, if they are supposed to be captured.

Comment: What's the difference between `.+?` and `.*`?

Comment: @robbie0630 `+` means 1 or more, where `*` means 0 or more.  The inclusion/exclusion of the `?` will make it greedy or non-greedy.

Comment: how can we put an OR condition here ? that is, check abc or xyz ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 /.+?(?=abc|xyz)/

Comment: @JohnWrensby- Thanks. This .+?(?<=abc|xyz) gets me the abc/xyz text as well.

Comment: I was trying to use sed on Mac, but the do not support using "?" this way, so I switched to perl.

Comment: This doesn't work in multiline. The question asks for "anything"

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey you can replace the . with [^] and it will work.

Comment: @einord if it needs to work with line breaks, you can add the /s flag to your regex.

Comment: I have noticed that this fails to select anything if the pattern your looking for does not exist, instead if you use `^(?:(?!abc)(?!def).)*` you can chain to exclude patterns you don't want and it will still grab everything as needed even if the pattern does not exist

Comment: what about blank or space? what's the RegEx for that?

Comment: This will not work with Google Apps Script RegExes, the "s" flag doesn't work there. So you need to use [\\S\\s] as a workaround catch-all (make sure it's double-escaped)

Comment: The regex must start with `^` / `\A` to actually only always fetch the first occurrence.

Comment: how do I display the look ahead value

Comment: @robbie actually .* means 0 r more chars, .+ means 1 or more chars

Answer (score 217):

If you're looking to capture everything up to "abc":

```
/^(.*?)abc/
```

Explanation:

`( )` capture the expression inside the parentheses for access using `$1`, `$2`, etc.

`^` match start of line

`.*` match anything, `?` non-greedily (match the minimum number of characters required) - [1]

[1] The reason why this is needed is that otherwise, in the following string:

```
whatever whatever something abc something abc
```

by default, regexes are *greedy*, meaning it will match as much as possible. Therefore `/^.*abc/` would match "whatever whatever something abc something ". Adding the non-greedy quantifier `?` makes the regex only match "whatever whatever something ".

Comment: Thanks, but your one *does* include the abc in the match. In other words the resulting match is "whatever whatever something abc".

Comment: Could you explain what you're ultimately trying to do? If your scenario is: (A) You want to get everything leading up to "abc" -- just use parentheses around what you want to capture. (B) You want to match the string up to the "abc" -- you have to check the abc anyway, so it needs to be part of the regex regardless. How else can you check that it's there?

Comment: `sed` doesn't seem to support non-greedy matching, nor does it support look-around (`(?=...)`). What else can I do? Example command: `echo "ONE: two,three, FOUR FIVE, six,seven" | sed -n -r "s/^ONE: (.+?), .*/\1/p"` returns `two,three, FOUR FIVE`, but I expect `two,three`...

Comment: @CoDEmanX You should probably post that as your own separate question rather than a comment, especially since it's specifically about sed. That being said, to address your question: you may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed). Also note that in your example, a non-greedy aware interpreter would return just `two`, not `two,three`.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the link though. Why would it return just `two`? There's a comma in `two,three`, but no space.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I missed the space in your regex. Confirmed it: `echo "ONE: two,three, FOUR FIVE, six,seven" | perl -pe 's/^ONE: (.+?), .*/\1/'` gives `two,three`

Comment: This is how **EVERY** regexp answer ***should*** look
- example and **explanation of all parts**...

Comment: in notepad++ (.*)abc will find anything before "abc", abc included

Comment: The 'greedy' mention was super helpful, thank you! I've been doing greedy regex for so long, time to change.

Comment: how can we put an OR condition here ? that is, check abc or xyz ?

Comment: This will not work with Google Apps Script RegExes, the "s" flag doesn't work there. So you need to use [\\S\\s] as a workaround catch-all (make sure it's double-escaped)

Answer (score 99):

As [Jared Ng and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-can-i-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-exp/7124811#7124811) @Issun pointed out, the key to solve this kind of regular expression like "matching everything up to a certain word or substring" or "matching everything after a certain word or substring" is called "lookaround" zero-length assertions. [Read more about them here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

In your particular case, it can be solved by a positive look ahead: `.+?(?=abc)`

A picture is worth a thousand words. See the detailed explanation in the screenshot.

[image: Regex101 Screenshot]

Comment: `.+?(?=abc)` copy-pastable regex is worth more.

Comment: What about excluding leading spaces?

Comment: shareable link also is worth more than screenshot, just kidding, thanks for the answer

Comment: Who is "Issun"? What answer does it refer to?

Comment: Issun's account no longer exists. But they are referring to "look around" - see the links I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 32):

#### Solution

`/[\s\S]*?(?=abc)/`

This will match

> everything up to (but not including) the exact sequence `"abc"`

as the OP asked, *even if the source string contains newlines* and *even if the sequence begins with `abc`*. However be sure to include the multiline flag `m`, if the source string may contain newlines.

#### How it works

`\s` means any **whitespace** character (e.g. space, tab, newline)

`\S` means any **non-whitespace** character; i.e. opposite to `\s`

Together `[\s\S]` means **any character**. This is almost the same as `.` except that `.` doesn't match newline.

`*` means **0+ occurrences** of the preceding token. I've used this instead of `+` in case the source string starts with `abc`.

`(?=` is known as **positive lookahead**. It requires a match to the string in the parentheses, but stops just before it, so `(?=abc)` means "up to but not including `abc`, but `abc` must be present in the source string".

`?` between `[\s\S]*` and `(?=abc)` means **lazy** (aka **non greedy**). i.e. stop at the first `abc`. Without this it would capture every character up to the *final* occurrence of `abc` if `abc` occurred more than once.

Comment: `/[\s\S]*?(?=abc)/` doesn't match the first *abc* see this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/ca012132e25a).

Comment: Yes it does, but it's hard to see. Try turning off the 'global' flag. Taking your example text "whatever whatever something abc something abc", without the global flag it matches "whatever whatever something ". With the global flag, it does multiple matches up to the final "abc".

Answer (score 9):

You need a look around assertion, like `.+? (?=abc)`.

See: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html)

Be aware that `[abc]` isn't the same as `abc`. Inside brackets it's not a string - each character is just one of the possibilities. Outside the brackets it becomes the string.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer it match "whatever whatever something abc something abc" as well, while the others not, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/c40ccefd5ec6).

Answer (score 8):

For regex in Java, and I believe also in most regex engines, if you want to include the last part this will work:

```
.+?(abc)
```

For example, in this line:

```
I have this very nice senabctence
```

Select all characters until "abc" and also include abc.

Using our regex, the result will be: `I have this very nice senabc`

Test this out: https://regex101.com/r/mX51ru/1

Comment: the OP doesn't want the "abc" to be included. He wants something like this [one](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/7016376771bf).

Answer (score 8):

Match From Start Till before "ABC" or "Line End" if no ABC

**(1) Matches whole string if string does not contain ABC anywhere**

**(2) Does not match empty string**

*(Not checked for strings with line breaks)*

```
^.+?(?=ABC|$)
```

Comment: You should add the `\i` flag to works. see this [example](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/72f80253508f).

Answer (score 7):

In Python:

`.+?(?=abc)` works for the single line case.

`[^]+?(?=abc)` does not work, since python doesn't recognize [^] as valid regex.
To make multiline matching work, you'll need to use the re.DOTALL option, for example:

```
re.findall('.+?(?=abc)', data, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 5):

So I had to improvise... after some time I managed to reach the regex I needed:

[image]

As you can see, I needed up to one folder ahead of "grp-bps" folder, without including the last dash. And it was required to have at least one folder after the "grp-bps" folder.

The text version for copy-paste (change 'grp-bps' for your text):

```regex
.*\/grp-bps\/[^\/]+
```

<sub>I ended in this Stack Overflow question after looking for help to solve my problem, but I didn't find any solution to it :(</sub>

Comment: No text version? 

Answer (score 3):

I would like to extend the [answer from sidyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-can-i-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-exp/7124976#7124976) for the *case insensitive* version of the regex.

If you want to match abc/Abc/ABC... case insensitively, which I needed to do, use the following regex.

```
.+?(?=(?i)abc)
```

Explanation:

```
(?i) - This will make the following abc match case insensitively.
```

The other explanation of the regex remains same as sidyll pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

This will make sense about regex.

The exact word can be got from the following regex command:

```
("(.*?)")/g
```

Here, we can get the exact word globally which is belonging inside the double quotes.

For example, if our search text is

> This is the example for "double quoted" words

then we will get "double quoted" from that sentence.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your attempt to help. I find it however  hard to see how this helps the goal stated in the question. Can you elaborate? Can you apply it to the given examples? You seem to focus on handling of `"`, which to me seems irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Hi, I have explained how to get the word or sentences in between the special characters. Here our question is also "anything until the sequence of special characters". so I tried with double quotes and explained it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't specify whether the succeeding character sequence is optional or not, but all other answers assume that the sequence is always given. So here is one, if the sequence is optional.

For instance, if matching code up to a line comment like `foo # ...` or `foo // ...`, the line comment itself may be optional, but one may still want to match the preceding code.

In this case, I would use `^(?:(?!abc).)*` (or for line comments: `^(?:(?!#).)*` or `^(?:(?!\/\/).)*`).

Explanation: 
`^` marks the beginning of the line. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, because a regular group would additionally capture the last matching letter in a group, which we don't need. 
Inside the group, we use negative lookahead `(?!)` and a `.`, so everything is matched, except for a specific sequence. This is repeated 0 to unlimited times with `*`. Use `+` instead, if you only want to match non-empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need subexpressions. You can use the normal `()` brackets for subexpressions.

This part is from the [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) manual:

> Back References and Subexpressions
>
> The back-reference \n, where n is a single digit, matches the substring
> previously matched by the nth parenthesized subexpression of the
> regular expression.

Doing something like `^[^(abc)]` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. Putting the abc in parentheses doesn't seem to make any difference. They are still treated as "a OR b OR c".

Comment: `[^...]` means "not any of the characters within the square brackets, rather than "not the following token", so this doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

The `$` marks the end of a string, so something like this should work: `[[^abc]*]$` where you're looking for anything *not ending* in any iteration of `abc`, but it would have to be at the end

Also if you're using a scripting language with regex (like PHP or JavaScript), they have a search function that stops when it first encounters a pattern (and you can specify start from the left or start from the right, or with php, you can do an implode to mirror the string).

Answer (score -7):

Try this:

```
.+?efg
```

Query:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('abcdefghijklmn','.+?efg', '') FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
hijklmn
```