# RegEx in PHP preg_replace: Show all numbers up until any other character

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I need to find all numbers in a string up until (but not including) anything that is not a number. If a number occours later on (after an occourance of a non-number-character) then it shouldn't be included either. I am trying with PHP's command `preg_replace`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres) helped me to write the following pattern:

```
.+?(?=[^0-9])
```

Which though doesn't work in:

```
preg_replace("/.+?(?=[^0-9])/", "", $entry);
```

where `$entry` is my string to search in.

As an example, I could have the following strings:

- 001Aa.bc
- 002a
- 003a4/.
- 004a(4)
- 005 (4).string-d
- 006-34

from which I want to have:

- 001
- 002
- 003
- 004
- 005
- 006

My pattern seems to work in test-sites, like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Is my use of the PHP command wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just match for numbers? The assertion seems needlessly complex. Or is this part of a bigger regex?

Comment: `\d+` isn't ok good enough for you?

Comment: `\d+` will grab more than the numbers at the beginning.

Comment: @mario, I don't follow you. I need to get the beginning numbers of the strings just as described. If there's an easy way, please tell me.

Comment: None of these suggestions addresses the *question as asked* - only the OP would benefit from them. This is why it is important to answer the general question as asked that will be searched for by everyone else with a variety of legitimate motivations that are not a concern, rather than trying to find a workaround or alternative (as correct as they may be) for the OP's issue specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_match()

```
preg_match(/^(\d)+/, $search_me, $save_string_to_me);
```

While it's rubular and not explicitly php, I imagine something this simple works the same:
http://rubular.com/r/aqZhNC4nJq

Comment: What does `$save_string_to_me` contain? It seems it's an array...?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php That array contains the value obtained from the regex, among a few other things.

Comment: You can't read documentation? `[0]` contains the entire match, the rest contain the matches of the capture groups.

Comment: It was an answer to Steeven's question.

Comment: No need to be rude. This works like a charm. Thank's a lot both of you.