# Regexp - Match everything while not sequence of characters including new line

Tags: regex

I looked on [How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

But this is not my case
I need to get everything inside (`code) and (`)
Example

````
```code
this is i want to get
this is too
```
````

I tried this regex

````
```.+\s*(.+)\s*```
````

But it doesn't work with multiple line data. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: is `code` compulsory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

````
```[\s\S]*?```
````

You can simply use this.Or you can use your regex with `s` or `DOTALL` flag