# Regex match until another match

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that parses the properties of a product, for example:
"led met interne weerstand 1/4w 1k" would parse into:

```
[0] met interne weerstand  
[1] 1/4w  
[2] 1k
```

So far, I have this regex:
`/(?:met .*)|(?:(?:\d+\/)?\d+\w ?)|(?:\d+ ?in ?\d+)/`

And I'm trying to match `1/4w 1/4s 1/4w 1/4d 3 in 1 1% led met interne weerstand 1/4w` against it.

It doesn't work the way I want it to work:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1/4w ' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1/4s ' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1/4w ' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1/4d ' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '3 in 1' (length=6)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'met interne weerstand 1/4w' (length=26)
```

Met interne weerstand is also matching 1/4w, but I want 1/4w to be a seperate match.
How do I do this?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres

Comment: That's not what I need, because it's not an exact sequence of characters. It could also be "met {whatever} {whatever}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:met .*?(?=(?:(?:\d+\/)?\d+\w ?)|$))|(?:(?:\d+\/)?\d+\w ?)|(?:\d+ ?in ?\d+)

        ^^
```

A `non greedy` approach would work for you with a lookahead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/9

Comment: If I try that, I get:  `0 => string 'met ' (length=4)`

Comment: Is there no other way? Can you like, reference to a pattern or is there no such thing in regexes?

Comment: I did use the new code, and it does work, but the problem is that I will be creating quiet a few more patterns, and if I have to put them in the lookahead it could get a mess.

Comment: @FrozenDroid you can use `met [a-zA-Z ]*` if you want to capture only sentence..........if there are more patterns you can always club them together in `lookahead` with `|`.We need some solid pattern for `met ...` to make it stop or else `lookahead` :)

Comment: Yeah the problem here is, there isn't really a "pattern", that's what makes it really difficult for me :P I guess a lookahead is the only real solution here.   Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's not working. "met interne weerstand" doesn't have to match only if there's a match after it. I need it so you can also type "led met interne weerstand".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77169/discussion-between-frozendroid-and-vks).