# How can I strip the data:image part from a base64 string of any image type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, image, base64

I am currently doing the following to decode base64 images in Javascript:

```
    var strImage = "";
    strImage = strToReplace.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
    strImage = strToReplace.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    strImage = strToReplace.replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "");
    strImage = strToReplace.replace("data:image/bmp;base64,", "");
```

As you can see above we are accepting the four most standard image types (jpeg, png, gif, bmp);

However, some of these images are very large and scanning through each one 4-5 times with replace seems a dreadful waste and terribly inefficient.

Is there a way I could reliably strip the data:image part of a base64 image string in a single pass?

Perhaps by detecting the first comma in the string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var strImage = strToReplace.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
```

---

- `^` means *At the start of the string*
- `data:image` means *data:image*
- `\/` means */*
- `[a-z]+` means *One or more characters between a and z*
- `;base64,` means *;base64,*

Comment: I don't know if is better for performance, but logically I'd say "yes" (the replace and regular expression search for matches in the entire string, indexof breaks on the first char equal to it's parameter), maybe I'll do some perfomance test:

`var strImage = strToReplace.Substring(strToReplace.IndexOf(',')+1);`

Comment: `strToReplace.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "")`

Answer (score 35):

```
var solution = string.split("base64,")[1];
```

Splits the variable string at "base64," than take the second part.

Comment: I don't understand why so many of the accepted answers have wacky regex solutions. This is simple to understand and executes really quickly. Any downsides?

Comment: @JoshuaOhana well if there is another "base64" in the encoded string ... otherwise not that i know ...

Comment: That's impossible. `,` is not a valid base64 encoding character.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me :

```
var strImage = strToReplace.split(',')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question looking for a way to strip any header. So just wanted to share this:

```
Regex.Replace(strToReplace, @"^.+?(;base64),", string.Empty))
```

Got this from an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/2022255) which describes how to:

> Match any characters as few as possible until a "abc" is found, without counting the "abc".

Comment: I like this replace answer because it not only handles any file type, but also doesn't error if you are passed a base64 string that _isn't_ prefixed with data:

`file.base64.replace(/^.+?(;base64),/, '')`

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
/[data:image\/[a-z]*;[a-z0-9]*,.*]/gm
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [startWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) so you won't have to scan all the object. it's performance should be much better

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me Swift 5:

```
let ourBase64String:String = "base64 string"
let base64StringArray:[String] = ourBase64String.components(separatedBy: "base64,")
if(attachmentArray.count > 0){
   print(attachmentArray[1])
}
```