# How to get only BaseCode 64 from array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, uri

I am getting basecode 64 image from json. So from rest API I am getting basecode 64 image under the array. I want to take only base code from array object in javascript.

I am sharing myjson sample

```
ImageKey:data:image/jpg;base64,[data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAEGANIDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD2ZlqNl+arG2m7a2JKrLuWodtWmWmsu6syiKil20baACnbaWloAKfRRQAUUtFABRR3p9ABRRS0AFFFPoAKKKKACiiigAopaKAEopaKAEopaKAHMtRstTdqStCSDbTWWpmWm7aAK7LuprLtqx5dNZazKIafS+XRtoASloooAKKGbbQrf3qCgp9MZttOWgkdRTWpzMq0FD6Ki8z/AL6oZnb7qr/31QBLRTNzfxLTt1BI6iin0AMop9FABRRRQAUUtFABRT6K0JI6TbUjLTaAG7aGjqTbS1mUQMtRstWmWo5FVfvfdoAqtTeabcXaRLurm9Y8URQfLH8zf3VqecuEDopJ0i+8y/8AfVU5L6CL7zr/ALrV5zfeJp5N21P+BNXP3WrXUjbmbd/Dtj+X/wBBrL2pXIezR6pby7vJljZl/hVqtQ3sUqfu3Xd/vV89yak7Squ9lk3L91q0rHxNqNi6s0rfe+ZZKPahyHuVxKsCMzN8qr/ern9W8UWttJtkljVVb726vPdS8dXV/AsS/u2T/Z+9XI3lzPPtn3NJG3+191qqUwhA9mtfGmms/wB3b/tM1dNY6lb3satbzrJu/u1896bLuk/vfxfe/wDHq6K1u54JFe1lbd/D/eWs/amvsT3JafXBaH4xfbtvEZtv3mWu2sbuC+tlnt28yNvutureE+cwnDlLC0+o6etUQLRS0UAFFFFABRT6KACimU+tCQpdtJS0AFFG2iswI2bbWPrWqRWUbeY6tJ/d/hWna9rEWn2zNvXzNvy15fql9LfTszO3l1lOrym8Icxc1jXXu2ZVdlj/APQqwZpFj/1m5pJPuqv3qLiX7Mu5k8xm+WNV+bd/tVHHGqq090/zN8rN/wCyrXLz8x0chG0HmRtu+9H/AN8rUckCLB8zMy7vmZvvM1Wt3mxs23y7dP4f71Z/23zJGfZ8qttjqxEf2RY/n2+XM3+rX/nmv97/AHqb9iVm8+4XdHFH/wB9bf8A4qpreVZ7n/x5mat6+jRUs4FX5mVZJV/u/wB1aoZxsenu11bvN8u9vm/3WrYXSX+y3Vv/AMtF/fR7V/76X/vn/wBBraurF7u+t1/6aLu/8d+WptUk+zXisvzbo12rUlnNx6WsnlyqvyruZf8A2Zf/AGatRrbaquv8Xy7l/vf7VSea1pdyJIu5d27/AHl/iqO3k2yzWu5drLQQQ7mil3bdsn3WX+9Wtoutz6FeLLC3nWMv+sj3Vn3ETSxKzNtmX5d3+1/C1Nh2TweQy7ZG+Xb/AHWo5+QiZ7Zp93Be20dxav5kMi7lq0teQ+Cddl0TUGsrpmktZG2/7StXrkLpKivG25W+7XVCfOYTgSUUU+qICiiigAooooAZT6ZT60JClpq06gB9ZXiDUk03TZJZG2t91V/vNWkzLGjM33VryfxVrP8AbOqqkLf6LF93/a/2qxqz5SqUOaRk61qE99dNLM3yt91d1Ud27+Lb/d/+KqvdS/Mzf3vlqvJP83y/7tcB6BpKyq0k8jbdu1V3fw1V3ee/zfLDEu7/AHV/+yrNvLtpJ1iX/Vp/D/epzXa7miZvljbzJf8Aab+7VAamoTq0UcC/L5nzN/0zX/4qsu6ZY0VIdqtt+Xb822mtK3zM3zMzf+PVNDbM3yMvzSfe/wBmgrkJNBiZnaVl/dqvzf7VQzXsqzzSsu1p5Gk/4DWtIywaeyL91vlrHk/eSszL97/x3/O2rIkXtD1Zrm7j3N/q59v+98v/ANjUniKR/MhZfvLFuX/gLMrVi6evlz7l/hk3f+PVqeIm3QWbL8rRySR/+gt/8VR9okddSeZ5Mu5mjX5W/wB1v8tUkjMt4rM33V+9VfRds8E1vIy+Yv7v/P8AwKm6h961bdt/dtHL/s/3aCDcXbJArr977rVVZfut91l+9t/u/wB7/gNGjzr+8ST+KrF5uhbcq/NH93/aVqgCHVIGkiW4Vf3n3ZK7r4e679pi+y3DbmX+KuTs9ksGxW+b7y/+y1Dp8r6TqqyruVd3/jtawmTM9uVadtqnpNytzaxurblddytWhtrqOcj207bUm2jbQBHtoqTbRQBVopKWtCRy06mrUOoXaWNnNcTfdjXdWYHI/ELxAttE2m27bZHX96391a858zy7bezfvJf/AB1f4adqE76hqElxM25pZN27/ZrN1aVvM+Vttcc58x2QhyFW4uV2szfd/wDZazZLto5Lf+9Kyt/8VUN9L8iru+822sea58zUGbd8sS7aiEDY0pr3ymZo2/fM3/fNWLVttsq/xMys1c/DuluWVm+826ui022uL2VlWJtrN/wGrCBoafGzMrL8zN91f7tdJZ2nkRMzNuZvmZqm0nQniVd25mrcuNP2233fvVkdkIHC3UrStt/5Zq3zVnyStJPs/iZWatzUrRoNOjX/AJaTy7f+ArurF02JrnWbj5flWP5f++qqBhOA3UpPskq7V+8u6pr67WSxVlb7sm6ptatPMuY/7qrtrn49+24t5PvK25auBjOHvEi6g0F356/xfKy/3q6C+ngltmljbcr/ADK1cXdRtsVv+en/AKFVrSbvbBNbzf3ty1qYHTaTOsnyq33o/wC9/FW9HP8AaYI2/wCWir83+1XA6Tdtbahs/h3ba6K3u/lhb+Fvvf8AfVZTgBe0+78i8ZN37tm3LW9eIk8Ct/u/N/stXH3TeXfK27dHL/47XUaDO08EkEn+sT+H/wBCqJAdt8Pb1vKm06Rv3kTbo/8AdrvI23LXkOlztp+r28+77rbWr1q3b+H+98y110p+6ZTJqNtPorQyGUU+igDPpaSlrQBy1xPxU1LyNMhs42/eTt/46v8An/x2u2WvG/H18174smVf9XbL5a/8B+9/49WNWfulUviMWP5ZWb+FV21h6tLt8xv7zVrNKsdnvb+9XI6xcs1rC396T5v++q4jtKN1Iyyru/hWqdraS3M+yNWZn+Wrnltczqqt8u7b/wCPV6F4N0ZYJFnkTc38K/7VXzlwhzFXw34FdVW4vG2sy/xV3mm6bpenx7Zp4VkX+Gtix0hp133jf8B/u1NeaXAqttVmaoOr4CGGSy2/LL/wKpLhU8ptvzfLXPtA8UrbU2q1XreVvus1Sa85l61Yblt2/hjbbWD4d0/y7u8fb8vyrXoFxaLcx/8AstU9N01bbzt33WbdQSc7faX50W5V+auV1bSGgu/tqp8v3ZV/2a9Iutsasq1g3kEt3tXd96qgRM5OTQluY/l+ZZF3fL/C1czqGhXtlLv8pmVf4l/ir2DSfCybo181v/sa6abwlE0f7t23bf4v4q1OScD5tk3NcxyqvzLt3VvaXIssXzL8u2u08XeFEjZmWJYbhf7v8VcXZxvZSyW//fP+7RzmXLyl68VZYF/56L8u3/gVamh3KrPby7trN+7b/eX/AD/47WHdMzRbVbduo0G5aSVovus3zf8AAqn7JJ6BeL5u7b/d3V6N4Lvv7Q0iHc37yL921eZ2srSxKqt91a6DwHetaa1cWrN+7fa1VSmRM9MX5flqSmrTq6jASiiigDMWn0yitCB0kixozt91V3NXz/eTvPfX10zfM/zf99NXt3iKXyNDvn+7tiavD2XfZ3DfxNtWuTEHVhynqkyxaey/d2x1yeoM0umwv/dXdtra8RSboplX/dWsG6uVis4/lVlVtv8A47WUDomdN4B0aLUGmur68jsrdV3fvF3M3+6tevaGujKqvay3F3tX5WWNY1/9CavJdLu2i8KwrNErLK3lx7vvV6JtbT9FhWNfm2/NQawO2+3Wyr8ySR/7Xnr/APE1GurWEit8l1Iq/wDPFfMrx+48QSy332e3VZpG+6zfdWq91ret2l20TXlwqrJt2wrtquQJVT2Jo9NvkZoZ1Vv7rKystc/dW0tpJ5qq0kP/AD0X5lX/AHq5eHxBerBb3GqJ5kcvyrcRr8y/7396taG5ln1CGWzfdG38S/3amcC4TOy0f97F81SatGsUfy/LUOk6hPcxKkMVvHt/ihiVWam6pfXUTwxMnk+a23ztvzL/APE1kaSnIx20+6nfdJ5dvHu+9JJt/wDHfvVoR6fYWib7i63f7q/L/wCPba5vVJZV1BXXc0ar96s1dXa9ufIs2aeb/npIv7uOteQy5z0K2vtKR1+zSM3/AG3Vf/ZWrWXVIl+XyP4f4p//ALGvB5vEGqLIyteyblX5V8pdv/AquL4ivNP8lL7bteNZF2/d2/8AstVyGHtT2DWF0+9tv9JimVv70bq3/sq15r4m8O2cU7XGl3Xmqu393JH5bf8A2VbWm6ykkatv3Rv92o9Wga5tpFtYpvm/iWsyuQ8t1CT7Jc/3v4drfxU3R9ser7Vb92zfK3+y1R+PLSXSba1WaKRtvy+Zu+9/vVk6Tc7r63ff95q05DCXxHp1jL5E/wArbtvytWlbz/ZtVt5923c21m/2a59ZG81WX7zRrWozeevy/wAW3bWYHuWny+faRvu+8tWK5vwTetc6Qq/xKtdHXdA5QooooAy6KZRWhBg+Pp/K8L3n/TTbGv8A31XjcMm2OZf91v8Ax6vTPixP5Wg267v9ZOv/AKC1eXx/duG/3a4cR8R1Ycx9c/1S/wC01czdN5sVuir8rMu7/wAdrptaX97H/vVzNrta801P+ejL/wChVMDoPZrHQkn0/S0X7sUqyN/u7W/+xrrI4PMgZG+b+Gq+lssKqrfd+7WltaP5vvK38X8Nc/OekqXKYreFNOk2s0Sxt935ar3HhSBpFb7Vu/3o1auijg3Nujba3+7Un2KVv+Wu1f8AZWtecylSiY9joVnE0f2rzLtY/urM3yr/AMBqxfQJp9jcT2sSwbV+WNa3IbJIvm2szf3mqjqEDX/+jr80O795J/7LRzh7KJa8AxPHo8bzf66T5m/2qk8bRNJpG+P/AFiSLItbGk23lRbV+7Tr6282La33f4qkJHBxwNdxyMy7o5P3nlstOk0vTrmJVWKOFl+60a7dtb0dlFZbkZlWFm/dt/d/2abNpCztvjb5v9mq5yOSJysng21lnZvtW5W+9uVamk8G2G1d22Rl+80jbmaukh0h1+8zVch0+KNtzLuo55E+ygc3pPg61tLnzY22xt/yzX7v/j1dE1okf95f4a0FVVTaq7aqyTqrMtZTmawgeW/FTS1n0W63f8s/3i14npO6K7hXd8qyL/6FX0V8RNknh+8b/pk1fO6ssdyv+z81a0PhOTEQ949Ot9sktr/tLt/8erQs22rCrN/st/wFttY+myeZaWLr/FurWZts60GR6R8NZ91tIv3trV3Fea/DOdvtMifwsu7/ANBr0quul8JyzEopaK0JMqimU+tCDzr41SeXpWn7vlXzWb/x2vP1b93I395V3V3XxuXdpFm38Ks3/oNef2LeZafe+Zo1auHEfEdtH4TL1b5pIW/hrmbNlXWtNT+7Iv8A6FXTXUm6O3Rv4WauZ02PzPEdiv8An7zVMDVfEfQFruZl+b5a2IWeNf3e5axdN+7HW9Cy1ynr85ehivJNv+kSVYWyn/5aXUn/AAGmwz/u9qtRNfLGv3qoyGzW0USs80skm3+81V7OVpJ1bbthWsHWNXZmZY23U641u3ggjXeq/LQUejQyo0C7WqT5WRv7tef2viRfKX5vlqxN4oVY1+f5asynAuapLLBLI6ruh3fMrVJYxWcu14f3e7+61ZK+ILO5SSLzVk3f3ax9F1B4JNkm5VqAgeiLbNt+W4mX/tpUzWj7f+Piase11DzFVt1aC3u5fmqwmRtA0W5ldmb/AGqz7zcy/d+Za0mk3fNUMiq1c8w5zh/G0m7w/dI3/PNq+cVk/wBLj3f7v/j1fS3jiP8A4l0i/wDTNq+bZo1i1Nlb5v3nyrXVhzjxB6J4fbdbWq/xLHurck+W8Zv7y/8AstYPh9d0n3f9XEv+f/Hq3L5tt5My/wAO1aZidZ8OZGXVY938Xy/+O16zXjnw/bbqtr/10/8AZWr2Ba6qXwmEx9FMorQyMqimU+tCDgPjNH5nhqF/7sn/ALLXm+lt/ocbf9M69c+Jlo174TulX70bLJXjemt/obL/AHVrhxB24f4SndN+9Vf4UkrB0NVXxZaru/h/9matq8Zvt27/AJZyL/4996seRvsni6zl/vNt/wDHv/sqiB0Hulm3lxR7vl+Wr0c+7+Ks+zZZbWOhleNtq/drA7DUW7aP5Vaqd9dsyt8zVXaRloj2s25moLCxsWkbfM3zUappKS7X2/8AAq1rf5Y91WI4/NXbQBxbW0sHyxruWprfTXvWX7Q3lxrXYLpqr8/ytRDAjM38NWSZ+k6Ja2TM8a+ZJ/eaq+qabtl82Gt7y/LqGRvMVttBEJGXp9y0fys1bEd621fmrHuoF+9H96m2sv8AD/dqDU6SG53fxVaWXd92sOFmb7y1qWvy7agymc/4y/eWkn97y6+dbyPd4hVf70lfRHjKRVgmb+7HXz+u5tcuJ1/gVtv+83yr/wChV0UjkqnbeGYlljZ2/jl+X/gNXrhlaWRv4tzU7wzB5VtCsny7Y1Zv+BfNUd4v7vb/ABNIq/8As1SZHWfDmPdqdr/wKSvXq87+Gtl80lwy/LGu1f8AgX/7K16HXZS+E55/EFFFFamZkUUlLWhBX1CBbuzmt2+7KrLXgMds9tqE1rN8rKzRt/vV9CferyP4gab9k16a4Vdq3O1v+BLXNVh7p0YeZwupR7rbcv3l+7XP68yyW1rex/w7WrrLhVklZN3+sX5a5mSLzLa6tW27lbcq/wC9WEDqkereDdQW70iF1b+GuiVlbb81eR/C/UmjWSzkb5o2r1SFt33f4qxnH3jtpT54ly4tkki3Vh3H2qBv3cXmf7O6ukjb93U0MHmL81SanHzX2s/8sbL/AL6kp3/FQtH8sEn/AGzkWummtvLZmX5qat28S/LuWq5jWHKcrJJ4jtn3Nb3X/AWqFbvXvN3fZbhf+BV139ry/wAUUjVNDqSs27Z/30tMrngc7DfeI41VpLCaRf8AgNXrXUtUn+VdJuFb/rov/wAVW99pZl3VJb72b5qDlnKJi2c9xLOyXVrJC391lrYjsUVd38VWLiNdqt/dqSOVdq1BJDHHtXa1SLIy/wDAahkVVk+X7tV76dYkZt1SRM5Xx9feTY3DbvvfLXlfheyaedZZFbbPL5jf7q/5auo8eXLXrR2cbf6xqm8P2axJJLJ8qxL5a/5/3f8A0Kt/hicszUVWii3f89JGX/2WqbbfNZm+ZY/vVYaVZLmNVb93tZq6DwT4fbVL77RcJ/ocEm7/AK6Sbv8A2WiEDKcj0DwbZNZaDbrIu2SX941btMX5V20V3wOUKKKKAMen1ArbqkrQgfXPeNNJXUtGm2r++j+Za3qG2stZzGfNuoRywSskisskdUdUjb5b23X7y/Mte8a94QstQSTcirub7391q4+4+Gs9su6O9WaFvvRyLXL7LlOyFU8p02dItVjuIVZWb/WLXsWj3Pm2yv8ANXN3ngWCyZvOvPLX/npH/D/wGtTQbu3lg/0W4W5jRvL8xf4mWpnA1pVTsLWRWX71WoZF/wCBLXPrP5TfM3ytVqO72srK1c53wmbixeb92iPS3kb7vy02xufu/NWlby7pPvfLQalf+xH/AIVWhtIZV+5W5Hcr/eoaRfvbqDKZg/Ymj/hp21o62JmRl3Vk3kq0Ele4lVf4qo3V6sEG7cv/AH1RcTpub+Guf1S582NvLXcv8VAGkurpJdMm77tZOtap5m5Vrjbhmjud8bX3mf3Vb5f/AEGrlvHcXbbm3Rx/xf3qIHLOYQ2nm3LN/rLhm/791avJPKWOwt/mVfvN/eatDT9PnubZm0uJmjVfmmre8E+Ennb7Vq0Xlwr92FvvN/vVrGEpnPOZl+FfD0+ry7drR2sbfvJv/ZVr17T7SKyto4LdFjjVflWi1gitolihRY41/hVasV2whyHPOfMFJS0lUSFFMooA5+OSpmkVY9zNtVaxWlupYmazaFmb5Y/Lk3bv+Bf/AGNNs9LnbzJdW1GNpPvLDG21Yv8Ad3f+hUC5DSk1S3X/AFbST7f+feNpP/Qap3Gs3G3dDZTR/wDXaORf/QVatBYIGtlWSVZl/vNL97/vmquoafYT2zJJb28isu3d8u5f92p5y+Qx77Xdzbd80e7bt8yxuNu7/e21x/jTxXpumrI9x9hvbiOTy1hjb94u3+Fv7tHjDxRa+CdNaysUsZtUlX5WWDayr/ek+b5mrwfUr2e+vJri6laaaRtzSN/FQUbXibxbf6zuiZlgs1/1dvD91f8A4qtr4Q6l5d9dWEjfLKvmRr/tL/n/AMdrga2PAs/2bxVYtu27m2/99LUTLpfEfQCr5i7WqFoZY/utU0PzKrVYVv71cp6UBtnetF8rVqW+qKrfN96slo9zVHJHt+ZWqS4TOmj1Jf7/AMtSLqX91649mem+dL91d1BXOddJqC7fmese81b95+7+Zqo28Dz/ADTNtWrH2aKJflX5qgymUbi5ll+992oWXcu1qvNH/FUO3c3y0AVY4kX+HdXnPxC8RXEGq/2dauqwoq+Yq/8ALRq9SaBljZtvzV4D4kn+0+JtQnZvl81lX/gPy10UoHLiPdOm8H+PdW8L6nuhnZrN9vn27fMrf7v+1XvGj/ES31RV/s2ykvV2/M0Lbdrf3W3V8pySMzM33q1vDPiC80DUY7qzfbt/1ke75ZF/u11HFM+vrXX4pdv2qCS0Zv4ZGX/4qtS3ninj3wurLXlvhnX5/EFjHe6e1vHbyfLIrKzSRyfxL/tfw/8A2Vdlbyuu1v8AVsvy7v71USdLTKw7PVJWjVJntZptv/LOTbu/4DWlHco3yt8rL97dQBZopm7/AGqKAMltPiiiWKNfLVfu7f4ap3ljFKjKy/e+8396ry6hYMjP5s1tGsnk/wCkxNDuZl3fKsi7mqjcaxZrqENrGyzNLJ5f7tvmjb/aX+7/ALVSaGLcaN5PmNZ3FxAzfdXzGZVb+9t+7/47XM6hq95pC7tYiaS3VfmuI1/9C/h/9BrvLxVi3fMy/wCyzbq8X+NGoW+6G3j3fapfmZvMbaq/7v3aAPNfEWrS6zq9xeTN80jfKv8AdX+FayWqao6CSKpbGVra8t51ba0Uitu/4FTdtG2gIH0pYsslstWm+X7tZ/hv/SdAsbyNtyyRLu/75rWXay7q4z14ELNULVYkj3L8vy1D5XzfNSDkIWWj7v3qsNHUPlMzVJZJDJ8u1WqRmZqkt7arCwbW+ZaCCisbSNVqG0Xd81Wo1Rfu/M1WI49zfL/3zQBRvlgtLOaeT5Y4laRm/wB2vl2SRpZWdvvM25q98+MWrrpfhdrJW/0q+/dqq/wr/F/n/arwNq6qRwYiY2hVp22hVrU5z0r4M6/cWN5eaar/ALuePzI127vmX/7H/wBBr1JpHvrndefvv+mbfNH/AN8/dr578H3z6b4jsbiNWZlk27V+8275a9+0tri+WR5EmtGjbb+8jX5v++WaqJNq1trOCRXj07T/ADP732ZVb/x2tJbn5mdrdY12/NukZd3/AKE1ZselpdyKjXk3nJ8zLHJt/wC+l/4DWxJZXUdov9mtD9o3Lua4VvmXb/s/dapAd5lr/wA9z/31RTvN1T/nyH4Sx0UAdE1jcSRMl49rcxs3zL5W35f++q5HUtEb98kmnfZrdWby/LZbiDb/AAs0fysv/bP/AL6r0SZXWKRlVWb+FWbbWe1ykkrQSI0Nx/Csn8X+638VBR5fJctOu2H5oVb94rSbvL/2lZvvLXzr401T+1/EF5dRt+53eXF/urX0B8bli0nRZry1lktrq5/dssf3Zl/2v+A/xV80yL/tUAQUn3qdtpKAGU5Y2b5V+anKu5q+iPg38PLPS9Mt9e15Y2vrlfMtoZPm8mP+Fv8Aeagoo/CeO/stDjs9Ut5IJFZmjjk+VvL/AN2usurRYtzw/db7y03xVLBbana3Vq26P5reT5W2/wCz/wCgtVy1lWdFrlmevR9+BlyNuXb/AOO1GrVsSaes/wDDtb+9VeTTZVb7tQWZu75vmpvmqrVeaxlZvuM3/AartpNx8zbN1BJJDe/LUyzr/vVHa6fLu2sirWxZ6SisrzfN/s1JBVtYHufm+7HV6ae30+D+9JU19cxW0X+ztrkdUnedWbb8zfKv+zVkzPLfixFqN7qceqSJu0//AI945FbdtZW+bd/d/wDsa4Gvq6Oy8PabbWvhrVLNprjVbaRpfmXb8q7v4m+Vv7v+7Xzn428Ov4b1yazWVZ7WRfOtrlfuzQt91v8AP8S10wPNn8RztFO2/NTasgdHI0cqurfdbdX0J4Zkn1tY7i8lmhs2VfKtY227l/vSMv8A6D/dr5527mXd/u17Z8OdS8zw5psSqzTNI1uu1v8AgX/jq0AerafaRWkS29msNt/s7a1rqSeBVWztWuZn+6u7bGv+83/7VZum6f8AYraS4t4vM1CSP5mkkZvMb/ao0nUtevbaGW401bTcreYsnzMrLu+7t+9937zbf+BUEljztW/6Bcv/AIFx0Vj/APCeWPe08QA9x9h6f+O0UAepTQpKrxSorow2OjjIIrA8URjT9FleJV8iMGTywMFQPmJU/wAJHaiigJnkXx6tHvLT95L/AMewjP8AvFv/ANqvnd+GbPUNtooqihrL8tR4ooqQO0+G2gWWpancXeqvKLPT4xO8UKqxlx0HzV9JeGLWW4043elRWNhCDgebG1zJ93sxZcD2oooKOV8f6iy2E+n3ZW4ulZXjmji8lV+Zeq7mz96o/DVwzKoNFFYVT08J8J29kEaPlan2eWvy/wAVFFYmsxWIAztWqkjFvmoooIHMtQ3D7Vb2oooA5u4kM90xb7g/ho0iJbzX7KB/umTcf+A/NRRRAiZ61JplncwM00CsY14b+Jf90/w/dFeIfEjSLbxNo3jGT7LbWc3hu6je3kiX5nRhhlb8t3+9RRXaeWfPDfeplFFUAn8NeufA1ElN+W3Zj2bOem/r/wCgCiipA+gNDjHkq3dvlq5ZNcavJMkci21vFKySFVy8n49qKKALP/CK6WeqT5/6+JP/AIqiiigD/9k=]
```

I want to remove data:image/jpg;base64,[ ] and get only basecode value. Which is  in the array. I want only array value. **ImageKey** is the key.
How can I get final basecode64 value. I have seen one related link, But I am not able to solve the problem.[How can I strip the data:image part from a base64 string of any image type in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633061/how-can-i-strip-the-dataimage-part-from-a-base64-string-of-any-image-type-in-ja)

**I want only**

```
data:image/jpg;base64,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
```

If you open in browser then image will create.

Comment: how's the JSON looking?

Comment: Json format is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using replace

---

```js
x = "data:image/jpg;base64,[data:image/jpg;base64,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]"

console.log(x.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,\[(.*)\]/, "$1"))
```

Comment: It is working fine but It is breaking some basecode.

Comment: Can you run the code snippet, I'm getting the image

Comment: I have multiple image in call. That's why it is breaking. 70% images displayed. I have 20 images and only 16 is displaying

Comment: can you plz share one which is not displaying

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you like my question then upvote  for help others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "regex" to get the value you are looking after like so:

```js
const regex = /ImageKey:data:image\/jpg;base64,\[(.*)\]/;
const str = `ImageKey:data:image/jpg;base64,[data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAEGANIDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD2ZlqNl+arG2m7a2JKrLuWodtWmWmsu6syiKil20baACnbaWloAKfRRQAUUtFABRR3p9ABRRS0AFFFPoAKKKKACiiigAopaKAEopaKAEopaKAHMtRstTdqStCSDbTWWpmWm7aAK7LuprLtqx5dNZazKIafS+XRtoASloooAKKGbbQrf3qCgp9MZttOWgkdRTWpzMq0FD6Ki8z/AL6oZnb7qr/31QBLRTNzfxLTt1BI6iin0AMop9FABRRRQAUUtFABRT6K0JI6TbUjLTaAG7aGjqTbS1mUQMtRstWmWo5FVfvfdoAqtTeabcXaRLurm9Y8URQfLH8zf3VqecuEDopJ0i+8y/8AfVU5L6CL7zr/ALrV5zfeJp5N21P+BNXP3WrXUjbmbd/Dtj+X/wBBrL2pXIezR6pby7vJljZl/hVqtQ3sUqfu3Xd/vV89yak7Squ9lk3L91q0rHxNqNi6s0rfe+ZZKPahyHuVxKsCMzN8qr/ern9W8UWttJtkljVVb726vPdS8dXV/AsS/u2T/Z+9XI3lzPPtn3NJG3+191qqUwhA9mtfGmms/wB3b/tM1dNY6lb3satbzrJu/u1896bLuk/vfxfe/wDHq6K1u54JFe1lbd/D/eWs/amvsT3JafXBaH4xfbtvEZtv3mWu2sbuC+tlnt28yNvutureE+cwnDlLC0+o6etUQLRS0UAFFFFABRT6KACimU+tCQpdtJS0AFFG2iswI2bbWPrWqRWUbeY6tJ/d/hWna9rEWn2zNvXzNvy15fql9LfTszO3l1lOrym8Icxc1jXXu2ZVdlj/APQqwZpFj/1m5pJPuqv3qLiX7Mu5k8xm+WNV+bd/tVHHGqq090/zN8rN/wCyrXLz8x0chG0HmRtu+9H/AN8rUckCLB8zMy7vmZvvM1Wt3mxs23y7dP4f71Z/23zJGfZ8qttjqxEf2RY/n2+XM3+rX/nmv97/AHqb9iVm8+4XdHFH/wB9bf8A4qpreVZ7n/x5mat6+jRUs4FX5mVZJV/u/wB1aoZxsenu11bvN8u9vm/3WrYXSX+y3Vv/AMtF/fR7V/76X/vn/wBBraurF7u+t1/6aLu/8d+WptUk+zXisvzbo12rUlnNx6WsnlyqvyruZf8A2Zf/AGatRrbaquv8Xy7l/vf7VSea1pdyJIu5d27/AHl/iqO3k2yzWu5drLQQQ7mil3bdsn3WX+9Wtoutz6FeLLC3nWMv+sj3Vn3ETSxKzNtmX5d3+1/C1Nh2TweQy7ZG+Xb/AHWo5+QiZ7Zp93Be20dxav5kMi7lq0teQ+Cddl0TUGsrpmktZG2/7StXrkLpKivG25W+7XVCfOYTgSUUU+qICiiigAooooAZT6ZT60JClpq06gB9ZXiDUk03TZJZG2t91V/vNWkzLGjM33VryfxVrP8AbOqqkLf6LF93/a/2qxqz5SqUOaRk61qE99dNLM3yt91d1Ud27+Lb/d/+KqvdS/Mzf3vlqvJP83y/7tcB6BpKyq0k8jbdu1V3fw1V3ee/zfLDEu7/AHV/+yrNvLtpJ1iX/Vp/D/epzXa7miZvljbzJf8Aab+7VAamoTq0UcC/L5nzN/0zX/4qsu6ZY0VIdqtt+Xb822mtK3zM3zMzf+PVNDbM3yMvzSfe/wBmgrkJNBiZnaVl/dqvzf7VQzXsqzzSsu1p5Gk/4DWtIywaeyL91vlrHk/eSszL97/x3/O2rIkXtD1Zrm7j3N/q59v+98v/ANjUniKR/MhZfvLFuX/gLMrVi6evlz7l/hk3f+PVqeIm3QWbL8rRySR/+gt/8VR9okddSeZ5Mu5mjX5W/wB1v8tUkjMt4rM33V+9VfRds8E1vIy+Yv7v/P8AwKm6h961bdt/dtHL/s/3aCDcXbJArr977rVVZfut91l+9t/u/wB7/gNGjzr+8ST+KrF5uhbcq/NH93/aVqgCHVIGkiW4Vf3n3ZK7r4e679pi+y3DbmX+KuTs9ksGxW+b7y/+y1Dp8r6TqqyruVd3/jtawmTM9uVadtqnpNytzaxurblddytWhtrqOcj207bUm2jbQBHtoqTbRQBVopKWtCRy06mrUOoXaWNnNcTfdjXdWYHI/ELxAttE2m27bZHX96391a858zy7bezfvJf/AB1f4adqE76hqElxM25pZN27/ZrN1aVvM+Vttcc58x2QhyFW4uV2szfd/wDZazZLto5Lf+9Kyt/8VUN9L8iru+822sea58zUGbd8sS7aiEDY0pr3ymZo2/fM3/fNWLVttsq/xMys1c/DuluWVm+826ui022uL2VlWJtrN/wGrCBoafGzMrL8zN91f7tdJZ2nkRMzNuZvmZqm0nQniVd25mrcuNP2233fvVkdkIHC3UrStt/5Zq3zVnyStJPs/iZWatzUrRoNOjX/AJaTy7f+ArurF02JrnWbj5flWP5f++qqBhOA3UpPskq7V+8u6pr67WSxVlb7sm6ptatPMuY/7qrtrn49+24t5PvK25auBjOHvEi6g0F356/xfKy/3q6C+ngltmljbcr/ADK1cXdRtsVv+en/AKFVrSbvbBNbzf3ty1qYHTaTOsnyq33o/wC9/FW9HP8AaYI2/wCWir83+1XA6Tdtbahs/h3ba6K3u/lhb+Fvvf8AfVZTgBe0+78i8ZN37tm3LW9eIk8Ct/u/N/stXH3TeXfK27dHL/47XUaDO08EkEn+sT+H/wBCqJAdt8Pb1vKm06Rv3kTbo/8AdrvI23LXkOlztp+r28+77rbWr1q3b+H+98y110p+6ZTJqNtPorQyGUU+igDPpaSlrQBy1xPxU1LyNMhs42/eTt/46v8An/x2u2WvG/H18174smVf9XbL5a/8B+9/49WNWfulUviMWP5ZWb+FV21h6tLt8xv7zVrNKsdnvb+9XI6xcs1rC396T5v++q4jtKN1Iyyru/hWqdraS3M+yNWZn+Wrnltczqqt8u7b/wCPV6F4N0ZYJFnkTc38K/7VXzlwhzFXw34FdVW4vG2sy/xV3mm6bpenx7Zp4VkX+Gtix0hp133jf8B/u1NeaXAqttVmaoOr4CGGSy2/LL/wKpLhU8ptvzfLXPtA8UrbU2q1XreVvus1Sa85l61Yblt2/hjbbWD4d0/y7u8fb8vyrXoFxaLcx/8AstU9N01bbzt33WbdQSc7faX50W5V+auV1bSGgu/tqp8v3ZV/2a9Iutsasq1g3kEt3tXd96qgRM5OTQluY/l+ZZF3fL/C1czqGhXtlLv8pmVf4l/ir2DSfCybo181v/sa6abwlE0f7t23bf4v4q1OScD5tk3NcxyqvzLt3VvaXIssXzL8u2u08XeFEjZmWJYbhf7v8VcXZxvZSyW//fP+7RzmXLyl68VZYF/56L8u3/gVamh3KrPby7trN+7b/eX/AD/47WHdMzRbVbduo0G5aSVovus3zf8AAqn7JJ6BeL5u7b/d3V6N4Lvv7Q0iHc37yL921eZ2srSxKqt91a6DwHetaa1cWrN+7fa1VSmRM9MX5flqSmrTq6jASiiigDMWn0yitCB0kixozt91V3NXz/eTvPfX10zfM/zf99NXt3iKXyNDvn+7tiavD2XfZ3DfxNtWuTEHVhynqkyxaey/d2x1yeoM0umwv/dXdtra8RSboplX/dWsG6uVis4/lVlVtv8A47WUDomdN4B0aLUGmur68jsrdV3fvF3M3+6tevaGujKqvay3F3tX5WWNY1/9CavJdLu2i8KwrNErLK3lx7vvV6JtbT9FhWNfm2/NQawO2+3Wyr8ySR/7Xnr/APE1GurWEit8l1Iq/wDPFfMrx+48QSy332e3VZpG+6zfdWq91ret2l20TXlwqrJt2wrtquQJVT2Jo9NvkZoZ1Vv7rKystc/dW0tpJ5qq0kP/AD0X5lX/AHq5eHxBerBb3GqJ5kcvyrcRr8y/7396taG5ln1CGWzfdG38S/3amcC4TOy0f97F81SatGsUfy/LUOk6hPcxKkMVvHt/ihiVWam6pfXUTwxMnk+a23ztvzL/APE1kaSnIx20+6nfdJ5dvHu+9JJt/wDHfvVoR6fYWib7i63f7q/L/wCPba5vVJZV1BXXc0ar96s1dXa9ufIs2aeb/npIv7uOteQy5z0K2vtKR1+zSM3/AG3Vf/ZWrWXVIl+XyP4f4p//ALGvB5vEGqLIyteyblX5V8pdv/AquL4ivNP8lL7bteNZF2/d2/8AstVyGHtT2DWF0+9tv9JimVv70bq3/sq15r4m8O2cU7XGl3Xmqu393JH5bf8A2VbWm6ykkatv3Rv92o9Wga5tpFtYpvm/iWsyuQ8t1CT7Jc/3v4drfxU3R9ser7Vb92zfK3+y1R+PLSXSba1WaKRtvy+Zu+9/vVk6Tc7r63ff95q05DCXxHp1jL5E/wArbtvytWlbz/ZtVt5923c21m/2a59ZG81WX7zRrWozeevy/wAW3bWYHuWny+faRvu+8tWK5vwTetc6Qq/xKtdHXdA5QooooAy6KZRWhBg+Pp/K8L3n/TTbGv8A31XjcMm2OZf91v8Ax6vTPixP5Wg267v9ZOv/AKC1eXx/duG/3a4cR8R1Ycx9c/1S/wC01czdN5sVuir8rMu7/wAdrptaX97H/vVzNrta801P+ejL/wChVMDoPZrHQkn0/S0X7sUqyN/u7W/+xrrI4PMgZG+b+Gq+lssKqrfd+7WltaP5vvK38X8Nc/OekqXKYreFNOk2s0Sxt935ar3HhSBpFb7Vu/3o1auijg3Nujba3+7Un2KVv+Wu1f8AZWtecylSiY9joVnE0f2rzLtY/urM3yr/AMBqxfQJp9jcT2sSwbV+WNa3IbJIvm2szf3mqjqEDX/+jr80O795J/7LRzh7KJa8AxPHo8bzf66T5m/2qk8bRNJpG+P/AFiSLItbGk23lRbV+7Tr6282La33f4qkJHBxwNdxyMy7o5P3nlstOk0vTrmJVWKOFl+60a7dtb0dlFZbkZlWFm/dt/d/2abNpCztvjb5v9mq5yOSJysng21lnZvtW5W+9uVamk8G2G1d22Rl+80jbmaukh0h1+8zVch0+KNtzLuo55E+ygc3pPg61tLnzY22xt/yzX7v/j1dE1okf95f4a0FVVTaq7aqyTqrMtZTmawgeW/FTS1n0W63f8s/3i14npO6K7hXd8qyL/6FX0V8RNknh+8b/pk1fO6ssdyv+z81a0PhOTEQ949Ot9sktr/tLt/8erQs22rCrN/st/wFttY+myeZaWLr/FurWZts60GR6R8NZ91tIv3trV3Fea/DOdvtMifwsu7/ANBr0quul8JyzEopaK0JMqimU+tCDzr41SeXpWn7vlXzWb/x2vP1b93I395V3V3XxuXdpFm38Ks3/oNef2LeZafe+Zo1auHEfEdtH4TL1b5pIW/hrmbNlXWtNT+7Iv8A6FXTXUm6O3Rv4WauZ02PzPEdiv8An7zVMDVfEfQFruZl+b5a2IWeNf3e5axdN+7HW9Cy1ynr85ehivJNv+kSVYWyn/5aXUn/AAGmwz/u9qtRNfLGv3qoyGzW0USs80skm3+81V7OVpJ1bbthWsHWNXZmZY23U641u3ggjXeq/LQUejQyo0C7WqT5WRv7tef2viRfKX5vlqxN4oVY1+f5asynAuapLLBLI6ruh3fMrVJYxWcu14f3e7+61ZK+ILO5SSLzVk3f3ax9F1B4JNkm5VqAgeiLbNt+W4mX/tpUzWj7f+Piase11DzFVt1aC3u5fmqwmRtA0W5ldmb/AGqz7zcy/d+Za0mk3fNUMiq1c8w5zh/G0m7w/dI3/PNq+cVk/wBLj3f7v/j1fS3jiP8A4l0i/wDTNq+bZo1i1Nlb5v3nyrXVhzjxB6J4fbdbWq/xLHurck+W8Zv7y/8AstYPh9d0n3f9XEv+f/Hq3L5tt5My/wAO1aZidZ8OZGXVY938Xy/+O16zXjnw/bbqtr/10/8AZWr2Ba6qXwmEx9FMorQyMqimU+tCDgPjNH5nhqF/7sn/ALLXm+lt/ocbf9M69c+Jlo174TulX70bLJXjemt/obL/AHVrhxB24f4SndN+9Vf4UkrB0NVXxZaru/h/9matq8Zvt27/AJZyL/4996seRvsni6zl/vNt/wDHv/sqiB0Hulm3lxR7vl+Wr0c+7+Ks+zZZbWOhleNtq/drA7DUW7aP5Vaqd9dsyt8zVXaRloj2s25moLCxsWkbfM3zUappKS7X2/8AAq1rf5Y91WI4/NXbQBxbW0sHyxruWprfTXvWX7Q3lxrXYLpqr8/ytRDAjM38NWSZ+k6Ja2TM8a+ZJ/eaq+qabtl82Gt7y/LqGRvMVttBEJGXp9y0fys1bEd621fmrHuoF+9H96m2sv8AD/dqDU6SG53fxVaWXd92sOFmb7y1qWvy7agymc/4y/eWkn97y6+dbyPd4hVf70lfRHjKRVgmb+7HXz+u5tcuJ1/gVtv+83yr/wChV0UjkqnbeGYlljZ2/jl+X/gNXrhlaWRv4tzU7wzB5VtCsny7Y1Zv+BfNUd4v7vb/ABNIq/8As1SZHWfDmPdqdr/wKSvXq87+Gtl80lwy/LGu1f8AgX/7K16HXZS+E55/EFFFFamZkUUlLWhBX1CBbuzmt2+7KrLXgMds9tqE1rN8rKzRt/vV9CferyP4gab9k16a4Vdq3O1v+BLXNVh7p0YeZwupR7rbcv3l+7XP68yyW1rex/w7WrrLhVklZN3+sX5a5mSLzLa6tW27lbcq/wC9WEDqkereDdQW70iF1b+GuiVlbb81eR/C/UmjWSzkb5o2r1SFt33f4qxnH3jtpT54ly4tkki3Vh3H2qBv3cXmf7O6ukjb93U0MHmL81SanHzX2s/8sbL/AL6kp3/FQtH8sEn/AGzkWummtvLZmX5qat28S/LuWq5jWHKcrJJ4jtn3Nb3X/AWqFbvXvN3fZbhf+BV139ry/wAUUjVNDqSs27Z/30tMrngc7DfeI41VpLCaRf8AgNXrXUtUn+VdJuFb/rov/wAVW99pZl3VJb72b5qDlnKJi2c9xLOyXVrJC391lrYjsUVd38VWLiNdqt/dqSOVdq1BJDHHtXa1SLIy/wDAahkVVk+X7tV76dYkZt1SRM5Xx9feTY3DbvvfLXlfheyaedZZFbbPL5jf7q/5auo8eXLXrR2cbf6xqm8P2axJJLJ8qxL5a/5/3f8A0Kt/hicszUVWii3f89JGX/2WqbbfNZm+ZY/vVYaVZLmNVb93tZq6DwT4fbVL77RcJ/ocEm7/AK6Sbv8A2WiEDKcj0DwbZNZaDbrIu2SX941btMX5V20V3wOUKKKKAMen1ArbqkrQgfXPeNNJXUtGm2r++j+Za3qG2stZzGfNuoRywSskisskdUdUjb5b23X7y/Mte8a94QstQSTcirub7391q4+4+Gs9su6O9WaFvvRyLXL7LlOyFU8p02dItVjuIVZWb/WLXsWj3Pm2yv8ANXN3ngWCyZvOvPLX/npH/D/wGtTQbu3lg/0W4W5jRvL8xf4mWpnA1pVTsLWRWX71WoZF/wCBLXPrP5TfM3ytVqO72srK1c53wmbixeb92iPS3kb7vy02xufu/NWlby7pPvfLQalf+xH/AIVWhtIZV+5W5Hcr/eoaRfvbqDKZg/Ymj/hp21o62JmRl3Vk3kq0Ele4lVf4qo3V6sEG7cv/AH1RcTpub+Guf1S582NvLXcv8VAGkurpJdMm77tZOtap5m5Vrjbhmjud8bX3mf3Vb5f/AEGrlvHcXbbm3Rx/xf3qIHLOYQ2nm3LN/rLhm/791avJPKWOwt/mVfvN/eatDT9PnubZm0uJmjVfmmre8E+Ennb7Vq0Xlwr92FvvN/vVrGEpnPOZl+FfD0+ry7drR2sbfvJv/ZVr17T7SKyto4LdFjjVflWi1gitolihRY41/hVasV2whyHPOfMFJS0lUSFFMooA5+OSpmkVY9zNtVaxWlupYmazaFmb5Y/Lk3bv+Bf/AGNNs9LnbzJdW1GNpPvLDG21Yv8Ad3f+hUC5DSk1S3X/AFbST7f+feNpP/Qap3Gs3G3dDZTR/wDXaORf/QVatBYIGtlWSVZl/vNL97/vmquoafYT2zJJb28isu3d8u5f92p5y+Qx77Xdzbd80e7bt8yxuNu7/e21x/jTxXpumrI9x9hvbiOTy1hjb94u3+Fv7tHjDxRa+CdNaysUsZtUlX5WWDayr/ek+b5mrwfUr2e+vJri6laaaRtzSN/FQUbXibxbf6zuiZlgs1/1dvD91f8A4qtr4Q6l5d9dWEjfLKvmRr/tL/n/AMdrga2PAs/2bxVYtu27m2/99LUTLpfEfQCr5i7WqFoZY/utU0PzKrVYVv71cp6UBtnetF8rVqW+qKrfN96slo9zVHJHt+ZWqS4TOmj1Jf7/AMtSLqX91649mem+dL91d1BXOddJqC7fmese81b95+7+Zqo28Dz/ADTNtWrH2aKJflX5qgymUbi5ll+992oWXcu1qvNH/FUO3c3y0AVY4kX+HdXnPxC8RXEGq/2dauqwoq+Yq/8ALRq9SaBljZtvzV4D4kn+0+JtQnZvl81lX/gPy10UoHLiPdOm8H+PdW8L6nuhnZrN9vn27fMrf7v+1XvGj/ES31RV/s2ykvV2/M0Lbdrf3W3V8pySMzM33q1vDPiC80DUY7qzfbt/1ke75ZF/u11HFM+vrXX4pdv2qCS0Zv4ZGX/4qtS3ninj3wurLXlvhnX5/EFjHe6e1vHbyfLIrKzSRyfxL/tfw/8A2Vdlbyuu1v8AVsvy7v71USdLTKw7PVJWjVJntZptv/LOTbu/4DWlHco3yt8rL97dQBZopm7/AGqKAMltPiiiWKNfLVfu7f4ap3ljFKjKy/e+8396ry6hYMjP5s1tGsnk/wCkxNDuZl3fKsi7mqjcaxZrqENrGyzNLJ5f7tvmjb/aX+7/ALVSaGLcaN5PmNZ3FxAzfdXzGZVb+9t+7/47XM6hq95pC7tYiaS3VfmuI1/9C/h/9BrvLxVi3fMy/wCyzbq8X+NGoW+6G3j3fapfmZvMbaq/7v3aAPNfEWrS6zq9xeTN80jfKv8AdX+FayWqao6CSKpbGVra8t51ba0Uitu/4FTdtG2gIH0pYsslstWm+X7tZ/hv/SdAsbyNtyyRLu/75rWXay7q4z14ELNULVYkj3L8vy1D5XzfNSDkIWWj7v3qsNHUPlMzVJZJDJ8u1WqRmZqkt7arCwbW+ZaCCisbSNVqG0Xd81Wo1Rfu/M1WI49zfL/3zQBRvlgtLOaeT5Y4laRm/wB2vl2SRpZWdvvM25q98+MWrrpfhdrJW/0q+/dqq/wr/F/n/arwNq6qRwYiY2hVp22hVrU5z0r4M6/cWN5eaar/ALuePzI127vmX/7H/wBBr1JpHvrndefvv+mbfNH/AN8/dr578H3z6b4jsbiNWZlk27V+8275a9+0tri+WR5EmtGjbb+8jX5v++WaqJNq1trOCRXj07T/ADP732ZVb/x2tJbn5mdrdY12/NukZd3/AKE1ZselpdyKjXk3nJ8zLHJt/wC+l/4DWxJZXUdov9mtD9o3Lua4VvmXb/s/dapAd5lr/wA9z/31RTvN1T/nyH4Sx0UAdE1jcSRMl49rcxs3zL5W35f++q5HUtEb98kmnfZrdWby/LZbiDb/AAs0fysv/bP/AL6r0SZXWKRlVWb+FWbbWe1ykkrQSI0Nx/Csn8X+638VBR5fJctOu2H5oVb94rSbvL/2lZvvLXzr401T+1/EF5dRt+53eXF/urX0B8bli0nRZry1lktrq5/dssf3Zl/2v+A/xV80yL/tUAQUn3qdtpKAGU5Y2b5V+anKu5q+iPg38PLPS9Mt9e15Y2vrlfMtoZPm8mP+Fv8Aeagoo/CeO/stDjs9Ut5IJFZmjjk+VvL/AN2usurRYtzw/db7y03xVLBbana3Vq26P5reT5W2/wCz/wCgtVy1lWdFrlmevR9+BlyNuXb/AOO1GrVsSaes/wDDtb+9VeTTZVb7tQWZu75vmpvmqrVeaxlZvuM3/AartpNx8zbN1BJJDe/LUyzr/vVHa6fLu2sirWxZ6SisrzfN/s1JBVtYHufm+7HV6ae30+D+9JU19cxW0X+ztrkdUnedWbb8zfKv+zVkzPLfixFqN7qceqSJu0//AI945FbdtZW+bd/d/wDsa4Gvq6Oy8PabbWvhrVLNprjVbaRpfmXb8q7v4m+Vv7v+7Xzn428Ov4b1yazWVZ7WRfOtrlfuzQt91v8AP8S10wPNn8RztFO2/NTasgdHI0cqurfdbdX0J4Zkn1tY7i8lmhs2VfKtY227l/vSMv8A6D/dr5527mXd/u17Z8OdS8zw5psSqzTNI1uu1v8AgX/jq0AerafaRWkS29msNt/s7a1rqSeBVWztWuZn+6u7bGv+83/7VZum6f8AYraS4t4vM1CSP5mkkZvMb/ao0nUtevbaGW401bTcreYsnzMrLu+7t+9937zbf+BUEljztW/6Bcv/AIFx0Vj/APCeWPe08QA9x9h6f+O0UAepTQpKrxSorow2OjjIIrA8URjT9FleJV8iMGTywMFQPmJU/wAJHaiigJnkXx6tHvLT95L/AMewjP8AvFv/ANqvnd+GbPUNtooqihrL8tR4ooqQO0+G2gWWpancXeqvKLPT4xO8UKqxlx0HzV9JeGLWW4043elRWNhCDgebG1zJ93sxZcD2oooKOV8f6iy2E+n3ZW4ulZXjmji8lV+Zeq7mz96o/DVwzKoNFFYVT08J8J29kEaPlan2eWvy/wAVFFYmsxWIAztWqkjFvmoooIHMtQ3D7Vb2oooA5u4kM90xb7g/ho0iJbzX7KB/umTcf+A/NRRRAiZ61JplncwM00CsY14b+Jf90/w/dFeIfEjSLbxNo3jGT7LbWc3hu6je3kiX5nRhhlb8t3+9RRXaeWfPDfeplFFUAn8NeufA1ElN+W3Zj2bOem/r/wCgCiipA+gNDjHkq3dvlq5ZNcavJMkci21vFKySFVy8n49qKKALP/CK6WeqT5/6+JP/AIqiiigD/9k=]`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

or you can use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const regex = /ImageKey:data:image\/jpg;base64,\[(.*)\]/;
const str = `ImageKey:data:image/jpg;base64,[data:image/jpg;base64,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]`;

var found = str.match(regex);

console.log(found[1]);
```

Comment: The required result is captured in the match group: `(.*)` , and is accessible on `m[1]`

Answer (score -3):

I think you can split your `string` like this and choose the part that you want:

```
consoLe.log(string.split(",")[ ].replace("]", ""))  
</script>   
< html>
```

... and `string` is the value from your `ImageKey`.
You can try it.