# What would be the correct RegEx pattern to build a list of this music tracks?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

This is the string I'm working on (a part of a html file):

> "Tracklist:01.  Jai Uttal & Ben Leinbach - Govinda (Holmes Ives
>   Remix)02.  Edu Imbernon & Los Suruba - Fayer  03.  Hankat - Be The
>   First (Rosenstand Remix)04.  Matthias Vogt - Seven Summits05.  Mike
>   Dem & Richfield feat. Sowelu - I Got My Soul06.  Stergios - City
>   Groove07.  Roman Flügel - Teenage Engineering08.  Mario Basanov feat.
>   Monica Liu - Move On09.  Rufus T - Dreamwork10.  Arctic Lake - For Us
>   (Huxley Remix)11.  Chew Fu feat. Steve Clisby - Purple Rain (Mousse
>   T's Home A Lone Mix)12.  Ryan Davis - Brun (Matthias Meyer Remix)13. 
>   Martin Waslewski - Rasberry Heaven"

I can't find the regular expression that associated with `findall()` is going to give me :

> [01.  Jai Uttal & Ben Leinbach - Govinda (Holmes Ives Remix),02.  Edu
>   Imbernon & Los Suruba - Fayer  ,03.  Hankat - Be The First (Rosenstand
>   Remix),04.  Matthias Vogt - Seven Summits,05.  Mike Dem & Richfield
>   feat. Sowelu - I Got My Soul,06.  Stergios - City Groove,07.  Roman
>   Flügel - Teenage Engineering,08.  Mario Basanov feat. Monica Liu -
>   Move On,09.  Rufus T - Dreamwork10.  Arctic Lake - For Us (Huxley
>   Remix),11.  Chew Fu feat. Steve Clisby - Purple Rain (Mousse T's Home
>   A Lone Mix),12.  Ryan Davis - Brun (Matthias Meyer Remix),13.  Martin
>   Waslewski - Rasberry Heaven ]

I got `r('\d{2}\.\s{2}....')` but after `\s{2}` I can't find any pattern that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match every track and return all of them. Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClCYnt/3). It works also if there are numbers in titles (as long as they are not followed by a dot).

```
/\d{2}\.\s+.+?(?=\d{2}\.|$)/g
```

Comment: wow it seems to work thank you !!! I ll really have to analyze and understand the end of this regex, it was a bit of a hard one for a first day of learn regex so thanks for your help

Comment: this Look ahead feature is what I was looking for, now I'm trying to adapt this regex to only have the \artist + track name\ and not the \d{2}\.\s{2} at the beginning

Comment: got it :) /(?<=\d{2}\.\s).+?(?=\d{2}\.|$)/g
Thanks to you I learned a lot :)

Comment: And I learned something thanks to you :) About the un-greedy operator `.+?`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/5722505).

Comment: Its more complicated that it seems when you really go deep into it  :) I never read about Look Ahead and Look Behind before, the un-greedy operator was still a bit obscure

Answer (score 1):

I tried this. I think this will help you to find all.

```
/\d{2}.*/
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems it selects the whole string... /\d{2}\.\s+.+?(?=\d{2}\.|$)/g seems to work