# Regex positive lookahead is too greedy

Tags: regex

I am attempting to remove the `<span class="notranslate"></span>` of a string using a regex.
Basically it's because Google Translate API needs that kind of wrapping if some string should not be translated, which is what I need.

I have that regex to do this (it needs to handle new lines, that's why `[\S\s]` is used instead of `.`) :

```
<span class="notranslate">[\S\s]+(?=<\/span>)<\/span>
```

However when testing it, it is way too greedy because for that input for example:

```
<span class="notranslate">%1</span> per il seguente motivo: <span class="notranslate">\n</span> <span class="notranslate">%2!d!</span>
```

That regex gets the **whole string**. I was a little confused because many answers (including "[How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)") seems to indicate that `?` as a non greedy thing.

I need to have it find every `span` wrap with the `notranslate` class, not all of them if there are many.

Comment: Remove the `(?=<\/span>)` lookahead and replace `+` with `+?`.

Comment: Thanks, in fact it was just missing one ? after the +

Comment: Your lookahead is redundant. `a` = `(?=a)a`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that last comment?

Comment: Remove the `(?=<\/span>)` lookahead, it does nothing. Itmakes no asense.

Comment: Oh ok I got it, thanks. ```<span class="notranslate">[\S\s]+?<\/span>```