# Python - Regex on content between repeating strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which looks like this :

```
 Q 1. What is your age?

Ans. 15.

Q 2. What is your name?

Ans. My name is Bond. 


My full name is James Bond

Q 3. What is your favorite subject?
```

and so on... The answers can have multiple paragraphs. The text generally looks like  and so on.. I am trying to write a regex which gives me these pairs.
I want to separate out the question answer pairs. I have a regex which outputs the questions but am unable to figure out how to get the pairs? Please guide. The regex for questions is :

```
p = re.findall("""Q [0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*\.(.*?)Ans\.""", checkText, re.S)
```

Comment: Do you need to do this with a regex? wouldn't it be easier to use stringIO and iterate over the lines?

Comment: @jprockbelly - ya, this text is in a html page and there are other strings in between these questions. Will update the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: what about parsing the HTML? use lxml or BeautifulSoup

Comment: @jprockbelly - ya, since they were in different tags, I got this data through parsing. Actually, what you suggested earlier might be useful, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Tarun, post your input as html markup

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Sorry, can't do that. I can't share the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay with regex, here's some solutions:

1. Question only: `Q \d\..*?\?(?=.*(?:Ans\.)?)` (finds question without answer as well)
2. Answer only: `Ans\. .*?(?=\n\nQ \d\.)`
3. Question and answer (one pair): `Q \d\. .*?(?=\n\nQ \d\.)`

   ```
   Q "matches Q
   (space)
   \d "matches a digit
   \. "matches a dot
   (space)
   .*? "matches everything (also new lines, you must use Single Line option), lazy matching
   (?= "positive lookahead
       \n\n "matches two new lines
       Q \d\. "beginning of next question, same as before
   ) "end of lookahead
   ```

More about lazy (un-greedy) matching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/5722505)

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/JxZcAD/1) (improved to match last question as well)

Comment: Hey Egan, thats quite helpful, can you please explain the third point. That would be helpful for me to change it according to the corner cases in my strings! Thanks

Comment: @Tarun I added some explanation. You can use site like regex101.com to learn how regex works.

Comment: Thanks a lof for the help. :)