# I am not able to fix a greedy regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to capture from the beginning of the url to the first instance of the /blog in the example url

https://subdomain.website.com/groups/aa-var-group-members-only-two/blog/2017/10/22/blog-post-3

the regular expression i have right now is **(.*)/blog**

is greedy and captures till the the last instance of "/blog" i.e

https://subdomain.website.com/groups/aa-var-group-members-only-two/blog/2017/10/22/blog

while my expected result is

https://subdomain.website.com/groups/aa-var-group-members-only-two/blog

can someone help me fix the regular expression

Comment: Put a `?` after the `*`?

Comment: try `(.*)(/blog?)`, usually `?` makes stuff not greedy

Comment: @Avantol13 Putting a `?` after a regular letter `g` will make it match `/blo` too, still greedily in regard of the `(.*)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex too greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426456/regex-too-greedy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example, this

```
^(.*?)blog
```

That will capture all until the first blog mention

[image]

and you can play with it here https://regex101.com/r/nYmOeh/1 :)

`.*?` is the non greedy version of your initial example. Sidyll [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres) gave a perfect explanation on greedy vs non-greedy.

alternatively, capturing all (without blog):

```
/.+?(?=blog)/
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailed answer.  really helpful