# Extract first sentence in string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to extract the first sentence from following with regex. The rule I want to implement (which I know won't be universal solution) is to extract from string start `^` up to (including) **the first period/exclamation/question mark that is preceded by a lowercase letter or number**.

```
require(stringr)

x = "Bali bombings: U.S. President George W. Bush amongst many others has condemned the perpetrators of the Bali car bombing of October 11. The death toll has now risen to at least 187."
```

My best guess so far has been to try and implement a non-greedy [string-before-match approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/1156245) fails in this case:

```
str_extract(x, '.+?(?=[a-z0-9][.?!] )')
[1] NA
```

Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: Try [`sub("([a-z0-9][?!.]).*", "\\1", x)`](https://regex101.com/r/VxgRek/1)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. That certainly works with this example. Why is the last `1` of `October 11.` not also matched?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you only need to check for a single digit or lowercase letter, right?

Comment: Sorry I see you tweaked your suggestion. Looking at it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put the `[a-z0-9][.?!]` into a non-consuming lookahead pattern, you need to make it consuming if you plan to use `str_extract`:

```
> str_extract(x, '.*?[a-z0-9][.?!](?= )')
[1] "Bali bombings: U.S. President George W. Bush amongst many others has condemned the perpetrators of the Bali car bombing of October 11."
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxgRek/3).

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `[a-z0-9]` - an ASCII lowercase letter or a digit
- `[.?!]` - a `.`, `?` or `!`
- `(?= )` - that is followed with a literal space.

Alternatively, you may use `sub`:

```
sub("([a-z0-9][?!.])\\s.*", "\\1", x)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxgRek/2/).

**Details**

- `([a-z0-9][?!.])` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): an ASCII lowercase letter or digit and then a `?`, `!` or `.`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible (up to the end of string).

Comment: Doesn't work with sentences with `Mr.` and `Dr.` in the first sentence - eg. `Mr. Mahendra Prasad, a politician from Janata Dal (United) party, is a Member of the Parliament of India representing Bihar in the Rajya Sabha, the upper house of the Parliament . Second sentence etc.`

Comment: I think it should handle titles to not to match the end of sentence - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title

Comment: @jaggi Why do you add `{2}` to my solution? It is not in line with the current OP requirements. See *The rule I want to implement (**which I know won't be universal solution**) is to extract from string start `^` up to (including) the first period/exclamation/question mark that is preceded by a lowercase letter or number.* The sentence above are not the ones OP tries to match, so, yours is a different question.

Comment: ah, I see.  I don't want to open a new question just for this, So I'll just put it for reference in comments if anybody has a requirement for handling 2 char titles like me to get a `valid` first sentence - `([a-z0-9]{2}[?!.])\s.*`

Answer (score 3):

`corpus` has special handling for abbreviations when determining sentence boundaries:

```
library(corpus)       
text_split(x, "sentences")
#>   parent index text                                                                                                                           
#> 1 1          1 Bali bombings: U.S. President George W. Bush amongst many others #> has condemned the perpetrators of the Bali car bombing of Oct…
#> 2 1          2 The death toll has now risen to at least 187.
```

There's also useful dataset with common abbreviations for many languages including English. See `corpus::abbreviations_en`, which can be used for disambiguating the sentence boundaries.

Comment: Very useful. I've been hacking through horrible regex to deal with `Dr.` etc

Comment: @dmi3kno is there any python equivalant?