# regex in python: match any non-digit character between two words

Tags: python, regex

Hello I'm playing around with regular expressions in [pythex](https://pythex.org/) and i'm having troubles. i'm trying to take the following string

```
"RANDOM 1 ABBBABBBA SDFSBSBS WBWBSBW WBWBWBWB 10 EBEBEBEB EHRHSHSD EBWBBSHSHSB //"
```

and grab all the non-numeral characters between RANDOM and the forwards slashes. How do I do this with regular expressions? Help!

Comment: So you want to ignore the numerical characters but still grab everything else between RANDOM and //? Is it possible for you to use two regex?

Comment: two regex? as in two regex commands? i don't see why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
import re

s = 'RANDOM 1 ABBBABBBA SDFSBSBS WBWBSBW WBWBWBWB 10 EBEBEBEB EHRHSHSD EBWBBSHSHSB //'

pattern = r'(?<=RANDOM).*?(?=//)'
match = re.search(pattern, s)
textBetween = match.group(0)
notNumeric = re.sub(r'\d', '', textBetween)

print(notNumeric)
```

- (?<=RANDOM): looks for text preceded by RANDOM (lookbehind
  assertion).
- (?=//): looks for text followed by // (lookahead    assertion).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = 'RANDOM 1 ABBBABBBA SDFSBSBS WBWBSBW WBWBWBWB 10 EBEBEBEB EHRHSHSD EBWBBSHSHSB //'

for between_text in re.findall(r'(?<=RANDOM)(.+?)(?=\/\/)', text):
    for word_match in re.findall(r'\b[^\d\W]+\b', between_text):
        print(word_match)
```

Output:

```
ABBBABBBA
SDFSBSBS
WBWBSBW
WBWBWBWB
EBEBEBEB
EHRHSHSD
EBWBBSHSHSB
```

`(?<=RANDOM)(.+?)(?=\/\/)` :

`(?<=RANDOM)` is positive lookbehind, it matches the `RANDOM` before the text, `(.+?)` matches all the text in between and `(?=\/\/)` is positive lookahead, which matches the two `\/\/`'s. More about [`(.+?)(?=\/\/)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/9348376).

`\b[^\d\W]+\b` :

`\b` matches word boundaries, and `[^\d\W]+` is a *negated* set that matches digits and non-words (so it matches non-digits, and words); the `+` signifies it matches one or more characters.