# Regex Everything except Item ID

Tags: regex

I'm trying to matching everything in comma delimited string that is not a Change Notice (CN) id, which is an alpha-numeric id starting with "CN".
The string is a list of items separated by a comma, where each item entry shows the item id followed by a "~-~" and some jargon.

He's an example string:

> CN98765432~-~ECN for A01234 Rev A,CR00098765~-~ECR for A12345 SOME PART NAME,CN12345678~-~ECN for A12345 Rev A

In this string, I want to match everything except "CN98765432" (which appears at the beginning) and "CN12345678" (which appears at the end after the last comma)

I've tried using `.*(?=CN\d)`, which I assumed would grab everything that ends before a "CN", but that incorrectly matched

> CN98765432~-~ECN for A01234 Rev A,CR00098765~-~ECR for A12345 SOME PART NAME,

, which includes the initial CN.

I also tried `.*((?=CN\d)|$)`, but that matched the entire string.

I've looked at similar problems but I was not able to adapt the answers into something suitable for my issue.

[How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres/32702991)

[Regex everything but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256873/regex-everything-but)

How do I match everything except for the CN IDs?

I'm using regex ex inside a java based software, so I believe this is a JavaScript flavored regex.

Comment: if it's comma separated, maybe it's easier to just split it first?

Comment: I can split it and then filter out what I don't want, but its less efficient than  deleting regex matches so I'd like to see if using a regex is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example string you could try it like this to select all except "CN98765432" and "CN12345678" and as you state in your comment on karakfa's answer:

"*Ideally I would want CN98765432,CN12345678 to be all that's left*"

[`,?(?!CN\d+)\b[\w~ -]+`](https://regex101.com/r/vHVvgP/1)

**That would match**

- `,?` Match optional comma
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that asserts what is on the right side is not

  - `CN\d+` Match CN followed by one or more digits
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `\d` Word boundary
- `[\w~ -]+` Character class repeated one or more times with the characters you allow to match

Comment: Thank you!

Can you explain why `.*(?=CN\d)` didn't work?

Comment: @SomeOne [`.*(?=CN\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wgdl8R/1) does not select all that is not a Change Notice (CN) because `.*` selects any character zero or more times ([greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) until you encounter `CN` followed by a digit so it would match all until it encounters the last `CN\d`.

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier to just delete the matched pattern

```
$ sed -E 's/CN[0-9]+//g' file

~-~ECN for A01234 Rev A,CR00098765~-~ECR for A12345 SOME PART NAME,~-~ECN for A12345 Rev A
```

if you want to capture the patterns

```
$ grep -oP 'CN[0-9]+' file | paste -sd,

CN98765432,CN12345678
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep the CN's by deleting everything else. The software I'm using cannot "grab" matches, it can only delete them.



Ideally I would want `CN98765432,CN12345678` to be all that's left.