# Sed REMOVE / REPLACE double parentheses

Tags: python, linux, design-patterns, sed, parentheses

I have a python file, which has lots of double parentheses like this, which i would like to replace with single parenthesis.
Sometimes the print goes on for 2 lines or more.

```
print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))
print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))

print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))


print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))


print((something))
print((something))

print((something))

print((something))


print((something))



print((something))
```

I have tried a lot different ways to approach this. I think the easiest would be with sed. I have something like this:

```
grep -rl 'print((' test.txt | xargs sed -i "N;s/print((\(.*\)))/print(\1)/g"
```

The output looks like this:

```
print('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text')
print('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text')

print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))


print(('>>   # some text some text some text and ' 
+ 'some more text'))


print(something)
print(something)

print(something)

print(something)


print(something)



print(something)
```

Now with some lines it works but with some it doesn't, i think it is because of the N; but i need this in case it is multiple lines long..

What could i do to improve this pattern?

Comment: you could use `sed -z 's/print(\(([^)]*)\))/print\1/g'` for small enough input files.. but this would fail if content inside the parenthesis includes a `)` and assumes that input file doesn't contain ASCII NUL character...

Comment: also, to avoid issues due to input file names, use `grep -rlZ 'regex' | xargs -0 sed ...`

Comment: `perl -0777 -pe 's/print\(\((.*?)\)\)/print($1)/sg'` might do better than `sed` version as `))` being part of content inside parenthesis might be rarer than just `)`

Comment: @Sundeep sometimes it's like this: `print(( something, somethingelse() ))`

Comment: @Sundeep and i have to this for a directory, so `test.txt` would be replaced with `./`

Comment: yeah, I mentioned those points while suggesting the solutions.. try the perl one..

Comment: again, I mentioned that in the comment.. you should improve your sample data with these cases..

Comment: @Sundeep Why did you delete your answer? i wanted to mark it : )

Comment: well, you mentioned it didn't work for all cases.. so I deleted it

Comment: @Sundeep actually it worked on all my files maybe there are exceptions but for me it worked so i would like to accept it

Comment: ok, I've undeleted it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid issues due to input file names, use `grep -rlZ 'regex' | xargs -0 <command ...>`

if content within parenthesis doesn't have `))`, then you can use this

```
grep -rlZ 'print((' | xargs -0 perl -i -0777 -pe 's/print\(\((.*?)\)\)/print($1)/sg'
```

- `-0777` to slurp entire file content as a single string, so this solution not fit for large files that cannot fit memory requirements
- `.*?` is [non-greedy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)
- `s` modifier allows to match `\n` as well for `.`

When using `-i` option, you can specify a backup suffix (ex: `-i.bkp`) or prefix (ex: `-i'bkp.*'`) or even a backup directory (ex: `-i'bkp_dir/*'`) - these help in preserving the original copy for further use