# regex for symbol or nothing

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string where I need to parse the values such that it some times exist between[''] and sometimes not.

Eg:

```
Input
    1. blah .... REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr'], blah ....
    2. blah .... REASON: elm H1MM_rr, blah .... 
    3. blah .... REASON: elm H1MM_rr. 
    4. blah .... REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr'].
```

The elm H1MM_rr is just an example here. It could be any string after REASON:

I tried `REASON: ([^,. ]+)")`but this still not working for ['']

```
Output I am looking for = elm H1MM_rr
```

Can some one suggest me a regex(java pattern) which can work for both strings ?

Comment: Give your desired output in the question. It would be helpful. Which language you are using?

Comment: yes, please restructure your question so the input and output is much clearer~

Comment: also, which programming language are you using?

Comment: Try [`REASON:\s*(?|\['([^']*)']|([^,.\s]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/TTElaB/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\[')?elm('])?` should do the trick. This will match `elm`, `['elm`, `elm']`, and `['elm']`.

You also may want to use `(?:\[')?elm(?:'])?`. (Check the documentation that I've linked below.)

[`?` will match something 0 or 1 times](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

You have to escape the first `[`, otherwise it treats everything between the `[` and `]` as a character set.

## According to Your Edits

Now that you have clarified certain things and modified your question, the following code should work (at least in JavaScript): 
`REASON: (\[')?[\w/]{0,}(\s)?[\w/]{0,}('\])?`
`REASON: (?:\[')?[\w/]{0,}(\s)?[\w/]{0,}(?:'\])?`

From the following input:

`blah .... REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr'], blah ....`
`blah .... REASON: /lm H1MM_rr, blah ....`
`blah .... REASON: elm H1MM_rr.` 
`blah .... REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr'].`
`blah .... REASON: [' '].`

It will match:

`REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']`
`REASON: /lm H1MM_rr`
`REASON: elm H1MM_rr`
`REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']`
`REASON: [' ']`

You may find [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) useful. You may also find [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres) useful, if you'd like to modify the query to possibly make it more concise.

Comment: The elm H1MM_rr is just an example here. It could be any string after REASON:

Comment: @user3407267 ok, well, which characters would be allowed and which characters would not be allowed?

Comment: It will be always preceded with REASON:

Comment: sometimes it will be with [' '] and sometime not but will always end with either . or ,

Comment: @user3407267 yes, i know but which characters can be after reason and between the brackets and single quotes???

Comment: It would be a-z  A-Z _ /

Comment: @user3407267 umm... in your question above, you also include `1`, and `.`??? ALSO, where is the cutoff? in other words, should a match also include `, blah ....` and or `.` and or `.                                   ` at the end of each string?

Comment: sorry it include 0-9 as well.. the cut off is either , or .

Comment: @user3407267 i've edited my answer accordingly. does it work in Java??

Comment: @user3407267 well?

Comment: not exactly .. I am getting [
  "REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']",
  null
]

Comment: I tried - "REASON: (?:\\[')?[\\w/]{0,}(\\s)?[\\w/]{0,}(?:'\\])?"

Comment: @user3407267 um... ["**`REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']`**", null] is the correct output is it not????

Comment: But with this :"REAOSN: (\\[')?s*([^,.]+)?s*([^,.]+)('\\])?" I am getting = [

  "REAOSN: ['elm H1MM_rr']",
  "['",
  "elm H1MM_rr''",
  "]",
  null.string
]

Comment: Yeah..generally it will give me the expected string 2nd or 3rd element as the array.. I am trying to get tat string alone

Comment: @user3407267 you're not even using the query that i created for you. i'm sorry, but i've wasted enough time at this point trying to guess exactly what it is you're looking for. ["**`REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']`**", null] seemed like legit output that matched what you said you were looking for... in that particular output the string is the first element in the array... likely `ele[0]`

Comment: @user3407267 so `["REASON: ['elm H1MM_rr']", null]` is what you were looking for (right?), whereby in that particular output the string is the first element in the array, likely accessed by using something like `array[0]`

Comment: Tats true but I am trying to get just elm H1MM_rr

Comment: @user3407267 what do u mean? also, what did you mean by **I tried REASON: ([^,. ]+)")but this still not working for ['']** in your original question? please edit your question and try to make it as clear as possible