# Regex only matches specific whitespaces between delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

I need a regex which will match whitespace chars under some condition.
Let's say I have this string:

```
String s = "{ <class body declarations> }";
```

I want to apply Java replaceAll method only on the whitespaces between the two delimiters `<` and `>`, to obtain this string:

```
"{ <classbodydeclarations> }";
```

Is there a regex to do that?

Comment: Please take a look on that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres

Answer (score 0):

the following regex works, *however* it can be tricked by an unexpected `<`. see https://regex101.com/r/nBm213/2 for a demonstration.

```
(?:(?<=<).*?)( )(?:.*?(?=>))
```

feel free to improve on this answer.

Comment: With your solution the result is `{ <> }`

Comment: @GioAgu updated my answer with non-capturing groups