# Replace a string of certain pattern from a text file using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

#### Text file

I want to read all lines and remove `id="***"`. * means any value also want to remove the `id=` . This is not a HTML or XML. this is `txt` file. I want result in regex pattern. I have tried all the stack overflow result.

### abcd.txt

```
<table id="tb0705" frame="topbot" rowsep="0" colsep="0">
<label id="lb0015">Table 1.</label>
<para id="para0105">
...
```

I have already tried.

```
string []lines=File.ReadAllLines("abcd.txt");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string newLine=Regex.Replace(line, @"id=\".\"", "");// this is not replacing
    Console.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

Expected result.

```
<table frame="topbot" rowsep="0" colsep="0">
<label >Table 1.</ce:label>
<para >
...
```

The pattern remains same for all lines.

Comment: `.` means _any character_. `.+` means _any number of characters taking as much as possible_. `.+?` means _any number of characters taking as **less** as possible_, which is what you need. Use `@"id=\".+?\""`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TfgF5r/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

Comment: @ankurpramanik my bad! Either remove the `@` or use `@"id="".+?"""` instead.

Comment: working fine without giving ```@``` symbol.  Otherwise giving Error

Comment: Thank you # Ahmed Abdelhameed