# How can I parse command line input to separate command, stdin, stdout, and stderr? Regex: How to match up until string a OR string b?

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse log files which run a command in the following format:

```sh
cmd options < stdin > stdout 2>> stderr
```

Some commands don't use stdin; some don't use stdout.

I can easily separate the cmd; I'm having trouble writing regex which can give me the other portions.

I know how to match up until a **single** string:

[How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

I don't know **how to match up until string a OR string b**.

That is, I want to match options up until either < or > or 2>> occurs.

Trying something like the following doesn't work.

```py
import re

test = "cmd test1 test2 -c test3 < infile > outfile 2>> err"

optRegex = '.+?(?=>|<|(2>>))'
optRegex = re.compile(optRegex)

stdoutRegex = '>+?(?=>|<|(2>>))'
stdoutRegex = re.compile(stdoutRegex)

# get options
result = optRegex.search(test)
options = result.group()
rest = test[len(options):]
options = options.rstrip()

# get stdout
result = stdoutRegex.search(rest)
stdout = result.group()
rest = rest[len(stdout):]
stdout = stdout.rstrip()


print(options)
print(stdout)
print(rest)
```

Output:

```
cmd test1 test2 -c test3
>
 infile > outfile 2>> err
```

In hindsight, this is probably easier with a loop and scanning for start and end characters, but I'm curious about a regex solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `^(.+?)(< .+?)?(> .+?)?(2>> .+)$` should capture the four sections of your input into separate groups.

Comment: Perhaps match until the first occurrence of either `< or > or 2>>` and then match what comes after and split on either of those