# How to cut content before sentence?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have in my content a few paragraphs and want to cut everything before when I find for example: **This is a comment statement**

I tried with `str_replace()` but this is not possible with this method and with `preg_replace` but on every validation my content stay untouched.

Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Take a look at strrpos and substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace` will not work in you case. Try `preg_replace` and remove the first matching pattern -

```
preg_replace('/.+?(?=This is a comment statement)/', '', $your_string, 1)
```

[Detailed explanantion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

Comment: it works with one-line string, can it be implemented for multiline strings?