# How can i remove all characters started with # from inside a div element using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As mentioned on the title here is a div element

```
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

I use this jquery code to get the whole content of the div element and store it in a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $itemdesc = $('#description').text();
</script>
```

but how can next remove the content that start with the # hashtag?

Comment: Woah, 5 answers for this very simple question. Too much attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove up to the end of the line that contains the `#`, use `replace` with this regex `#.*\n`:

```js
var $itemdesc = $('#description').text();

var $result = $itemdesc.replace(/#.*\n/g, '');

console.log($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep.
# And this is the text i want to remove.
And keep this as well. 
# And remove this as well.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the content is always the same structure - ie: text you want + '#' + text you dont want - then simply split the text content on the character and pass only the first portion to a variable.

```js
let content = document.querySelector('#description').textContent.split('#')[0].trim();


console.log(content); // gives "This is an example text i wanna keep."
```

```html
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

Comment: You code wont work with muliple lines. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57835331/1248177)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to `split` the text based on the `#` character and just use the first element of the resultant array.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#description').innerHTML;
const split = text.split('#')
console.log(split[0].trim());
```

```html
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

Another option would be to use regular expressions, like in this example: [How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres).

Comment: This wont work if you have one line without '#' after a line with '#'

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with simple regex...

```js
var $itemdesc = $('#description').text();

console.log($itemdesc.replace(/^#.*\n/gm, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this in one line with `filter`:

- Split text by newlines
- Filter every lines starting with anything but '#'
- Concat back every lines

```js
$('#description').text($('#description').text().split("\n").filter(x => !x.startsWith('#')).join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

Same solution without JQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('#description').innerText = document.querySelector('#description').textContent.split("\n").filter(x => !x.startsWith('#')).join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

This code will also work with multi lines:

```js
document.querySelector('#description').innerText = document.querySelector('#description').textContent.split("\n").filter(x => !x.startsWith('#')).join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="description" class="bold"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And this is the text i want to remove.
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but seems inefficient, especially if there are a lot of words you have to iterate over!