# Regular expression to replace string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I created a regex to replace a substring from a string. But, apparantly the **regex I created is not correct**. Please guide

I want to replace a regex from the Html string, but as there are multiple tags like that, **it treats them as one tag,** it replaces all the tags.

**Method used:**

```
pattern = <figure id="attachment_5438".*</figure>
html = html.replaceFirst(pattern, "text to replace");
```

Following is the **Html** that in which I want to replace the string

```
Temp
<figure id="attachment_5438" align="aligncenter" width="1832"><img ng-test class="size-full wp-image-5438" src="link/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ATA070219portfolio_img02.jpg" alt="California red-sided garter snake (Thamnophis sirtalis infernalis) photographed at the Cheyenne Mountain Zoo in Colorado Springs, Colorado." width="1832" height="1374" /> California red-sided garter snake (<em>Thamnophis sirtalis infernalis</em>) photographed at the Cheyenne Mountain Zoo in Colorado Springs, Colorado.</figure>  <figure id="attachment_5439" align="aligncenter" width="1832"><img ng-test class="size-full wp-image-5439" src="link
 /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ATA070219portfolio_img03.jpg" alt="Spanish shawl nudibranch (Flabellinopsis iodinea) photographed at the Research Experience and Education Facility, or REEF, at UC Santa Barbara in Santa Barbara, California." width="1832" height="1374" /> Spanish shawl nudibranch (<em>Flabellinopsis iodinea</em>) photographed at the Research Experience and Education Facility, or REEF, at UC Santa Barbara in Santa Barbara, California.</figure> abc
```

For better clarity, I nn have attached the string in the image as well

[image]

Comment: `.*` regex by default is greedy, meaning it takes as many characters as possible. You need to make your regex non-greedy with `.*?`.

Comment: <figure id="attachment_5438".+?<\/figure>

Comment: Mandatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454. Also please see: [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166), [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres), you could try

```
<figure id="attachment_5438".+?(?=</figure>)</figure>
```

Comment: it worked for me, thanks much.