# regex in regex block

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying parse a value in a block.

Let me explain with an example.

I have the following text :

```
started xx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xx
xx xxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx found 9999 xxxxx xxxxx
xxx xx xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx stored 9999 finished
```

I'm  trying to catch the value between "started" and "finished"

I tried something like this

```
(?<block>started(.|\n)*finished)
```

but I don't know how to add the value `\d+` near "stored"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

Comment: The regex does not work with Python `re`, `(?<block>` must be `(?P<block>`. Do not use `(.|\n)*`, use `.*?` with `re.DOTALL`. If you need to captured the digits try `re.findall(r'started(.*?(?:stored\s+(\d+)\s+)?)finished', text, re.S)`

Comment: `re.match("started .+?found (\d+) .+? stored (\d+) finished", flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you provided does not work with Python `re`, as `(?<block>...)` is not a supported named group syntax, it must look like `(?P<block>...)`.

Also, it is recommended to avoid `(.|\n)*` that is a very inefficient construct, use `.*?` with `re.DOTALL`/`re.S` or `(?s)` instead.

If you need to captured the digits alongside the digits after `stored` and before `finished` (and if this is optional) use

```
re.findall(r'started(.*?(?:stored\s+(\d+)\s+)?)finished', text, re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYyPqd/1)

**Details**

- `started`  - left-hand delimiter
- `(.*?(?:stored\s+(\d+)\s+)?)` - Gropup 1:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `(?:stored\s+(\d+)\s+)?` - an optional group matching

    - `stored\s+` - `stored` and 1+ whitespaces
    - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `finished` - right-hand delimiter.

Comment: @IgorShilov As usual, `with open(file + ".out.txt", 'w') as fw: fw.write(updated_contents)`

Comment: @IgorShilov I have no idea what you mean. Please add the non-working code to the question and explain the expected behavior.

Comment: in my case regex need for current  log file more 15 mb  if i use this code it  didin't work  with ⁣ ⁣open ( 'log.log) as reading:
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣line=reading.read()
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣(r'\d+.*07.*?started\s+\w+(.*?(?:stored\s+(\d+)\s+)?)finished.\w+', line, re.DOTALL)
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣if regex:
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣for res1, res2 in regex:
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣print res2

Comment: it works only ide  if you try make it for work with file  you need  construct "with open (file, r): as read"  then you should  read  file by line - "readlines()" or full - "read()" , which method i shoud  use and  how write corret  code in this case. see: https://ideone.com/zK2k0g

Comment: @IgorShilov You seem to be using Python2. Apart from this, everything looks good, `reading.read()` is the right method since it reads all file contents into a single variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205749/discussion-between-igor-shilov-and-wiktor-stribizew).