# How to match everything up to double newline "\n\n" using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following Python string

```py
str = """
....
Dummyline

Start of matching
+----------+----------------------------+
+   test   +           1234             +
+   test2  +           5678             +
+----------+----------------------------+

Finish above. Do not match this
+----------+----------------------------+
+  dummy1  +       00000000000          +
+  dummy2  +       12345678910          +
+----------+----------------------------+
"""
```

and I want to match everything that the first table has. I could use a regex that starts matching from

```
"Start"
```

and matches everything until it finds a double newline

```py
\n\n
```

I found some tips on how to do this in another stackoverflow post ([How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)), but it doesn't seem to be working for the double newline case.

I thought of the following code

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"Start[^\n\n]")
matches = pattern.finditer(str)
```

where basically

```py
[^x]
```

means match everything until character x is found. But this works only for characters, not with strings ("\n\n" in this case)

Anybody has any idea on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can match `Start`  until the end of the lines, and then  match all lines that start with a newline and are not immediately followed by a newline using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
^Start .*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^Start .*` Match `Start`  from the start of the string `^` and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\r?\n)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not a newline
  - `.*` Match 0+ times any character except a newline
- `)*` Close the non capturing group and repeat 0+ times to get all the lines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNzGcW/1)

Comment: I am not really sure what this does but it works. Thanks a lot! I will spend some time in order to understand this regex

Comment: @Andrew I will add an explanation in a moment.