# how to regex this link?

Tags: python, regex

I want to regex a list of URLs.
The links format looks like this:
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pushkin'

The part I need:
`en.wikipedia.org`

Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for `\w` etc. which would only match the domain, you're effectively looking for anything up to where the URL arguments start (the first `?`):

```
re.search(r'[^?]*', URL)
```

This means: from the beginning of the string (`search`), all characters that are not `?`. A character class beginning with `^` negates the class, i.e. not matching instead of matching.

This gives you a match object, where `[0]` will be the URL you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that wihtout using regex by leveraging [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://sales-office.ae/axcapital/damaclagoons/?cm_id=14981686043_130222322842_553881409427_kwd-1434230410787_m__g_&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxc6PBhCEARIsAH8Hff2k3IHDPpViVTzUfxx4NRD-fSsfWkCDT-ywLPY2C6OrdTP36x431QsaAt2dEALw_wcB"

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
print(f"{parsed_url.scheme}://{parsed_url.netloc}{parsed_url.path}")
```

Outputs

> https://sales-office.ae/axcapital/damaclagoons/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this looks like it would work:

`\w+://\S+\.\w+\/\S+\/`

Answer (score 0):

Based on: [How to match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres)

```
.+?(?=\?)
```

so:

```
re.findall(".+?(?=\?)", URL)
```