# Support Regex that has more than one forward slash in domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to support endpoints such as

```
/myendpoint:
/v1/myendpoint:
/v3/someotherendpoint:
```

This regex:

```
const regexPattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:';
```

Only answers to `/myendpoint:`

How can we do an or operation to support both cases ?

Comment: Add a match for zero or more subsequent sequences like the first one, starting with `/`.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it something like recursive your existing solution for its multiple instance.

**Example:**  `(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*:`

**Play:** https://regexr.com/6jka3

The character `*` in a regular expression means "**match the preceding character zero or many times**"

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to test if it matches or not, you can just use a repeated pattern, like this:

```js
const tests = ['/a', '/a/b/c', 'nope'];
const pattern = /^(\/[0-9a-z-]+)+$/i;

tests.forEach(str => console.log(str, pattern.test(str)));
```

If you want to match each part, it gets a lot trickier and uglier, and you'd better off testing if it works then just use `split('/')` to get the parts.