# regex - stop at first pattern found

Tags: regex

I have this block of text'

```
/dev/disk0s2   3.6Ti  2.9Ti  796Gi    79% 383906083 104366287   79%   /
/dev/disk0s3   1.2Ti  1.3Ti  796Gi    79% 383906083 104366287   79%   /
```

using (see https://regex101.com/r/44YqQe/1)

```
(\/dev\/disk0s2).* (\d*\.\d+)?Ti
```

Desired result: 3.6

Actual Result : 2.9

Question

How do I match and stop at the first match with this regex?

Comment: Are you using it with `sed` or similar tool? If not use `(\/dev\/disk0s2).*? (\d*\.\d+)?Ti` instead.

Comment: If bash tools are used you'll probably need something like `(\/dev\/disk0s2).* (\d*\.\d+)?Ti  (\d*\.\d+)?Ti`. Or simple `(\/dev\/disk0s2)\s*(\d*\.\d+)?Ti` if it is expected that only spaces are between disk and size.

Comment: (\/dev\/disk0s2)\s*(\d*\.\d+)?Ti did it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on you situation you could use one of the following solutions.

If it is expected that only spaces are between disk and size: `(\/dev\/disk0s2)\s*(\d*\.\d+)?Ti`.

If any symbol could be expected, and you're using tool supporting PCRE-like regexes: `(\/dev\/disk0s2).*? (\d*\.\d+)?Ti`. It will match first number before `Ti` by utilizing [lazy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976).

If bash tools (like `sed`) are used, you'll probably need something like `(\/dev\/disk0s2).* (\d*\.\d+)?Ti  (\d*\.\d+)?Ti`.