# Remove HTML anchor tag but keep anchor text from bash command line

Tags: bash, unix, sed

How would I remove the anchor tag but keep the anchor text in Bash? So I want to remove everything except the words Example text.

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example text</a>
```

So if I do:

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com">Example text</a>' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

That removes all HTML. I'm looking to remove just anchor tags but also retain the anchor text, "Example text" in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
$ echo '<a href="http://example.com">Example text</a>' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
Example text
```

Or, alternatively, you could also use `perl` instead of `sed` since a [non greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103149/183066) regular expression would be helpful here:

```
$ echo '<a href="http://example.com">Example text</a>' | perl -pe 's/\<.*?\>//g'
Example text
```

Note: Using regex to parse HTML is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/183066), but for this small task I'd say it's fine to stick to the tools available in the command line.

Edit: To remove just anchor tags, you can use the regular expression can be updated as follows:

```
sed -e 's/<\/\?a\s*[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: I'm looking to use sed to remove just anchor tags not all tags. Is that possible?

Comment: removing the anchor tags didn't work...it still displays everything I originally echoed out.

Comment: @user983223 Please could you provide an example an example of an input that isn't working?

Comment: echo '<a href="http://example.com">Example text</a>' | sed -e 's/<\/\?a\s*[^>]*>//g'

Comment: @user983223 That's working fine for me in Ubuntu 11.10 with sed 4.2.1

Comment: The original example works fine but it stips out all html. The Edit to remove just anchor tags did not remove anything. I'm on a Mac. I tried all sorts of things to try and find out my version number of sed but no luck...-V, --version and that isn't recognized.

Comment: if I do sed -e 's/<a\s*[^>]*>//g' then it looks like it will remove all anchor tags and leave all other html syntax. That is halfway there. I need the anchor tag text but I don't want the tag around it

Answer (score 1):

here's a helpful guide:
http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/unix/sed.html

Answer (score 0):

If your input is well formed, you could use XSLT from the command line. (I'd recommend [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), but [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) would be ok.):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer removes all tags from the HTML, not just the link.  A better Perl command that removes just the `<a>..</a>` (but not other tags) while leaving behind anchor text is:

```
perl -pe 's/\<a [^>]*\>(.*?)<\/a>/$1/gi'
```

Testing it on:

```
<html><A HREF="http://example.com/"><b>Anchor Text</b></A></html>
```

It leaves behind:

```
<html><b>Anchor Text</b></html>
```

To remove only links containing a specific URL (while leaving other links alone), you could use:

```
perl -pe 's/\<a [^>]*href\=\"http\:\/\/example\.com[^>]+\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/$1/gi'
```

You use it by piping text to it:

```
echo "<html>..." | perl -pe 's/...'
```

Or use it to modify a file in-place using the `-i` flag to perl:

```
perl -pe 's/...' -i file.html
```