# Substring of numbers from a Non Ascii string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a string which is read from a file and it contains all types of non-ascii characters like this

```
line=^AÀÀ^P^G^P^@^H15552655^@^@E$4c<84>%ÿ~^@^@^Ac<8f>/qu^Q»í&.WÈå
```

Now I just need to extract '15552655' number from this.

What I tried :

```
line=$(sed -n '1p' < file)

number=$(echo "${line//[!0-9]/}")
              or
number=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
```

But this returns '155526554', so I need a way to extract substring from the line that contains continuously at least 4 consecutive numbers [ Guaranteed that there will be atleast 4 numbers in that pattern ]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update-1 :

```
number=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/')
```

This seems to work for the above case, but it will fail if the input is of this format

```
line=^AÀÀ^P^4G^P^@^H15552655^@^@E$4c<84>%ÿ~^@^@^Ac<8f>/qu^Q»í&.WÈå
```

In this case it returns 4 i.e. it returns first run of numbers. I need to add something that says give me longest or more than 4 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `head` and `grep`:

```
head -1 filename | grep -o '[0-9]\{4,\}'
```

Here `[0-9]\{4,\}` matches any run of four or more digits. The `-o` switch tells `grep` to print only those matches (on a line of their own).

If this still gives you false positives, you could process those further to find the largest number in the bunch by using `sort` and `tail`, as in

```
head -1 filename | grep -o '[0-9]\{4,\}' | sort -n | tail -1
```

This will in turn:

- get the first line from the file,
- isolate all instances of four or more consecutive numbers,
- sort these numerically, and
- print the last of the sorted list, i.e. the largest one.

Comment: Perfect, this does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
number=$(echo "$line" | tr -cs '0-9' '\n' | awk '{if (length>l) { n=$0; l=length }} END { print n }')
```

Explanation: Double-quotes around `$line` prevent the shell from doing anything weird if the string contains certain shell metacharacters. `tr -cs '0-9' '\n'` replaces everything that isn't a digit with newlines, "squeezing" together runs of the replaced characters; this essentially produces a list of numbers in the file, one per line. Then in awk, the `{if (length>l) { n=$0; l=length }}` says that for each input line, if its `length` is longer than what it's seen before (`l`), set `n` to the current line and `l` to its length. The `END { print n }` part makes it print the longest line when it gets to the end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you break the line into comma-separated numbers and then examine those numbers to your heart's content:

```
line="^AÀÀ^P^G^P^@^H15552655^@^@E$4c<84>%ÿ~^@^@^Ac<8f>/qu^Q»í&.WÈå"

number=$(echo $line | sed -E 's/[^0-9]+/,/g')
echo $number
==> ,15552655,84,8,
```

Finding the longest is complex.  Here's one solution, but Gordon Davisson's solution is a one-liner.

```
#!/bin/bash


line="^AÀÀ^P^G^P^@^H15552655^@^@E$4c<84>%ÿ~^@^@^Ac<8f>/qu^Q»í&.WÈå"

number=$(echo $line | sed -E 's/[^0-9]+/\\n/g')
max_length=0
this_index=0
saved_index=-1

echo $number | 
{ while read num ; do
pieces[$this_index]=$num
this_length=$(echo $num | wc -c | sed 's/ //g')
if [ $this_length -gt $max_length ]  ; then
    max_length=$this_length
    saved_index=$this_index
fi
this_index=$(expr $this_index + 1)
done


echo maxnum is ${pieces[$saved_index]}

}
```

Comment: This would be great if I can fetch largest among them without splitting them and checking the length and all that. There could be numbers before '15552655' as well.

Answer (score -2):

If "H" character is prefix before number, you can use it as prevent to getting right number.

```
#!/bin/bash

line="^AÀÀ^P1^G88^P^@^H15552655^@^@E$4c<84>%ÿ~^@^@^Ac<8f>/qu^Q»í&.WÈå"
echo -e "line="$line"\n"

strA=$(   echo $line | sed -E 's/.*H([0-9]+).*/\1/g'   )
strB=$(   echo $line | sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'  )
strC=$(   echo $line | sed -E 's/.*\^H([0-9]+)\^.*/\1/g'   )
strD=$(   echo $line | sed -E 's/(.*)([0-9]{8})(.*)/\2/g'   )    # without 'H' prefix

echo $strA    # 15552655
echo $strB    # 1
echo $strC    # 15552655
echo $strD    # 15552655
```

But your question is duplicated ! > [sed extracting group of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260625/sed-extracting-group-of-digits)