# Extracting specific words using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a line like this

```
BR_MALLOC %p File - %s, Func - %s, Line - %u\n
```

This is actually a line from a C program which outputs the malloced address, the file where the custom malloc `BR_MALLOC` was called etc etc.

Now, I am running `sed` on this output to get just the malloced address (%p)

I tried this regular expression

```
$ echo "BR_MALLOC %p File - %s, Func - %s, Line - %u\n" | sed 's/BR_MALLOC\s+\(\S+\).*/\1'
```

Expected Output

```
%p
```

Output I get is

```
BR_MALLOC %p File - %s, Func - %s, Line - %un
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to escape the `+` ([docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)):

```
echo "BR_MALLOC %p File - %s, Func - %s, Line - %u\n" | sed 's/BR_MALLOC\s\+\(\S\+\).*/\1/'
%p
```

Comment: Can you explain why you added a `?` and also what is the greedy matching you are referring to?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I am getting this error
`sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`. If I take off `-r` my old ouput occurs. ie `?` has no effect :(

Comment: If you're sure you copied and pasted correctly, then our versions of `sed` behave differently. Try escaping the parantheses as `\(` and `\)` (it's not needed on my GNU sed version 4.2.1).

Comment: @Stacker sorry, my original answer was wrong, the issue is not about greediness. However, you still might want to get familiar with the concept, so: look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). However, `sed` seems to only support greedy matching (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about sed, but with perl your expression would work pretty much as is:

```
perl -pe 's/BR_MALLOC\s+(\S+).*/$1/'
```

Comment: Though I am currently working with `sed`, I'll surely keep in mind your `perl` solution too. Thanks! and +1 :)