# How to replace text using greedy approach in sed?

Tags: sed, greedy

I am parsing one file which has some html tag and changing into latex tag.

cat text

```
  <Text>A &lt;strong&gt;ASDFF&lt;/strong&gt; is a &lt;em&gt;cerebrovafdfasfscular&lt;/em&gt; condifasdftion caufadfsed fasdfby tfdashe l
 ocfsdafalised &lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;ballooning&lt;/span&gt; or difdaslation of an arfdatery in thdfe bfdasrai
 n. Smadfsall aasdneurysms may dadisplay fdasno ofadsbvious sdfasigns (&lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;str
 ong&gt;asymptomatic&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/span&gt;) bfdasut lfdsaarger afdasneurysms maydas besda asfdsasociated widfth sdsfudd
```

```
  sed -e 's|&lt;strong&gt;\(.*\)&lt;/strong&gt;|\\textbf{\1}|g' test
```

cat out

```
 <Text>A \textbf{ASDFF&lt;/strong&gt; is a &lt;em&gt;cerebrovafdfasfscular&lt;/em&gt;    condifasdftion caufadfsed fasdfby tfdashe locfsda
    falised &lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;ballooning&lt;/span&gt; or    difdaslation of an arfdatery in thdfe bfdasrain. Sma
      dfsall aasdneurysms may dadisplay fdasno ofadsbvious sdfasigns (&lt;span style="text-decoration: underline;"&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt
      ;asymptomatic}&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/span&gt;) bfdasut lfdsaarger afdasneurysms maydas besda   asfdsasociated widfth sdsfudd
```

Expected outputs should be \textbf{ASDFF} while i observe \textbf{ASDFF .........}. How to get expected result?

Regards

Comment: Please post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use perl regex instead.

```
perl -pe  's|&lt;strong&gt;(.*?)&lt;/strong&gt;|\\textbf{\1}|g'
```

Your problem is similar with [non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed). And next time you may want to simplify your case to point out the real problem. For example, don't just paste the raw html code, use this instead:

```
fooTEXT1barfooTEXT2bar
```

**Update**

If you just want the greedy approach, just ignore this.

Comment: Thanks, I have multiple expression how can i use all possible repalcement in one line in perl like perl -pe <exression1> -pe <expression2> ....

Comment: You may want a pipe instead, e.g. `cat file | perl -pe '<exp1>' | perl -pe '<exp2>' `

Comment: But for pipe, i need to do it so many times. My file is very big arnd 100 GB. Is there any way to do all at one time. Which means no need to scan file number of times.

Comment: @user15662: The best way to solve it may be to learn a little perl. I don't know if there is some one-line perl code to do these things. Perl is easy to learn and you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Is there any way to the same if data tags are in multiline.

Comment: @user15662:yes, perl can do it