# Delete Everything between $ including multiple lines in latex files

Tags: regex, perl, terminal, latex

I am working on laTex files, I need to delete everything between two $ including newlines and keep only english text.

I am using a command like this to process the files:

```
find "." -name "*.tex" | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\$[^\$].*?\$/ /g' *
```

Example:

```
Then use the naturality formula 

    $t_{G^{n-1}M} G^{i+1} (\epsilon_{G^{n-i}M}) 
    = G^{i+1} (\epsilon_{G^{n-i}M}) t_{G^n M}$ on the left-hand side.
```

OutPut:

```
Then use the naturality formula 
 on the left-hand side.
```

another example from file:

EXAMPLE:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $M$ is atomic and finitely generated;
\item $M$ is cancellative;
\item $(M, \le_L)$ and $(M, \le_R)$ are lattices;
\item there exists an element $\Delta \in M$, called {\it Garside element}, such that the set 
$L(\Delta)= \{ x \in M; x\le_L \Delta\}$ generates $M$ and is equal to $R(\Delta)= \{ x\in M; 
x\le_R \Delta\}$.
\end{itemize}
```

OUTPUT:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item   is atomic and finitely generated;
\item   is cancellative;
\item   and   are lattices;
\item there exists an element  , called {\it Garside element}, such that the set 
  generates   and is equal to $R(\Delta)= \{ x\in M; 
x\le_R \Delta\}$.
\end{itemize}
```

if you can notice ( $R(\Delta)= { x\in M; x\le_R \Delta}$.) can not be removed!!

Example 2 from different file, the input same as the output nothing has changed :

```
    Using the fact that   is atomic and that $L(\Delta)= 
\{x \in M; x \le_L \Delta\} M \pi_L(a) \neq 1 a \neq 
1 k \partial_L^k(a)=1 k$ be the
```

Comment: *"it works but not for all cases that I have in the files"* Please give some examples of the cases that aren't working, and a brief example document that you want to process. It's not fair to ask us to write software without seeing any input.

Comment: I edited back in your regex/command as that i relevant information to the question. I have also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is not matching when the text it should match spans multiple lines.

You have `[^\$].*?` which matches one character that is not `$` using `[^\$]` and then matches `.*?` which matches any character that is not a newline character zero or more times lazily. This works on your single line cases because of the lazy modifier trying to match a `$` before another `.`, but fails the multi-line cases because `.` will not match a newline.

Correct and more efficient would be `[^\$]*` which would match as many non-`$` characters as possible, including newlines.

So your command would would be

```
s/\$[^\$]*\$/ /g
```

or cleaner looking in my opinion to use non-standard delimiters and avoid the 'fencepost' look `/\`

```
s~\$[^\$]*\$~ ~g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZvkQ3/4)

Perl is processing your file line by line, which is another cause for the failing matches across newlines. There are a number of documented answers to this problem already on SO and written by people who know perl better than I: [How to match multiline data in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391855/how-to-match-multiline-data-in-perl)

Comment: unfortunately it did not work! for example this case has not been solved  ,  ..projection $I_{d,i}
\rightarrow M_{d,i} M_{d,0}$, where all the ..

Comment: Could you update your question with multiple examples of cases that are not working?

Comment: Why do you think it's "cleaner" to use non-standard delimiters for your substitution, especially the pipe character `|` which is a regex metacharacter? And why are you using the non-greedy quantifier when you have said that the greedy version is "more efficient"?

Comment: it looks nicer, notice i said 'imo' and gave it after the answer, thanks for the catch on the `?` it is more efficient to use the greedy, nearly cuts match steps in half