# .* too greedy in sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to extract a version number from some strings in bash without using too much additional packages. So far I tried `sed`.

Here is the API :

```
3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1    should give :  3.81
2.68-1ubuntu2        should give :  2.68
1:1.11.3-1ubuntu2    should give :  1.11.3
```

And here is my sed command so far:

```
echo ... | sed -r 's/.*([0-9\.]+).*/\1/'
```

However, the opening `.*` is too greedy, especially with the last case. I've tried some `.*?` and `.\{-}` without any success.

I can do it in two passes, but I would rather learn how to do it in one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed

Comment: @Tinctorius I'd rather not use perl, as stated in my question. But if there is no better way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is this ok for you?

```
 grep -Po "[\d\.]*(?=-)" file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat tt
3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1
2.68-1ubuntu2
1:1.11.3-1ubuntu2

kent$  grep -Po "[\d\.]*(?=-)" tt
3.81
2.68
1.11.3
```

Comment: Waow. Didn't know that grep could be used that way. I'm a little afraid of "This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features." (cf. man grep) but this is a very strong answer !

Comment: Exactly what I just about to post +1 You don't need to escape the period inside a character class however.

Comment: @sudo_O thx.. I always put a back-slash...seems to be unnecessary .

Comment: I'm using this technique again. What is the last part `(?=-)` ?

Comment: @Offirmo means "followed by `-`"

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the greediness you need to be more strict with the regexp:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)-.*/\1/' file
3.81
2.68
1.11.3
```

This will match version numbers with major, minor and build *(optionally)* marks, always followed by a hyphen.