# How do I write a SED regex to extract a string delimited by another string?

Tags: regex, sed

I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1 and I am trying to write a non-greedy SED regex to extract a string that delimited by two other strings. This is easy when the delimiting strings are single-character:

```
s:{\([^}]*\)}:\1:g
```

In that example the string is delimited by '{' on the left and '}' on the right.

If the delimiting strings are multiple characters, say '{{{' and '}}}' I can adjust the above expression like this:

```
s:{{{\([^}}}]*\)}}}:\1:g
```

so the centre expression matches anything not containing the '}}}' closing string. But this only works if the match string does not contain '}' at all. Something like:

```
{{{cannot match {this broken} example}}}
```

will not work but

```
{{{can match this example}}}
```

does work. Of course

```
s:{{{\(.*\)}}}:\1:g
```

always works but is greedy so isn't suitable where multiple patterns occur on the same line.

I understand `[^a]` to mean anything except `a` and `[^ab]` to mean anything except `a` or `b` so, despite it appearing to work, I don't think `[^}}}]` is the correct way to exclude that sequence of 3 consecutive characters.

So how to I write a regex for SED that matches a string that is delimited bt two other strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `[^}}}]` doesn't work.  A negated character class matches anything that is not one of the characters inside it.  Repeating characters doesn't change the logic.  So what you wrote is the same as `[^}]`.  (It is easy to see why this works when there are no braces inside the expression).

In Perl and compatible regular expressions, you can use `?` to make a `*` or `+` non-greedy:

```
 s:{{{(.*?)}}}:$1:g
```

This will always match the first `}}}` after the opening `{{{`.

However, [this is not possible in Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed).  In fact, I don't think there is any way in Sed of doing this match.  The only other way to do this is use advanced features like look-ahead, which Sed also does not have.

You can easily use Perl in a sed-like fashion with the `-pe` options, which cause it to take a single line of code from the command line (`-e`) and automatically loop over each line and print the result (`-p`).

```
perl -pe 's:{{{(.*?)}}}:$1:g'
```

The `-i` option for in-place editing of files is also useful, but make sure your regex is correct first!

For more information see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer - it's what I suspected as i knew about sed not being able to look ahead. I found that I didn't need to escape the capture group in your example: `'s:{{{(.*?)}}}:$1<:g'` (in fact, when I did, it didn't work).

Comment: @starfry, oops, you are right about the capture group.  That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you could do something like:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*\){{{\(.*\)}}}/\1\2/ ; ta'
```

With:

```
{{{can match this example}}} {{{can match this 2nd example}}}
```

This gives:

```
can match this example can match this 2nd example
```

It is not lazy matching, but by replacing from right to left we can make use of sed's greediness.