# replace a string upto and including the first instance of another string in OS X

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I'm trying to replace a string upto the first instance of a second string with sed (in OS X). My sed command unfortunately replaces everything up to the last instance of the second string.

my text:

`<li>lorem ipsum</li><li>dolor sit amet</li><li>something</li><li></li>`

I need to remove `<li>lorem ipsum</li>` so that the new line looks like this:

```
<li>dolor sit amet</li><li>something</li><li></li>
```

my sed command unfortunately replaces the whole line:

```
sed -i "" 's:<li>lorem.*</li>::'
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this with sed?

Thanks 
AleV

Comment: What about `sed 's:<li>lorem.[a-z]*</li>::'`?

Comment: More generally, `sed 's:<li>lorem[^<]*</li>::' -- that does not assume you have only letters in the text. Regular expressions, though, cannot in general parse XML which is not a regular language: You should be looking for an XML or HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest to what you want is this:

```
sed -i "" 's:<li>lorem[^<]*</li>::'
```

(pattern means include anything that is not a "<", i.e. up to the next tag).  With sed you'll have to decide one way or another for a terminating character or a set of valid characters.

.

The cleanest solution however would be of course be a non-greedy match, but sed does not offer that (see [non greedy regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed)) but using perl would be a solution according to the link:

```
perl -pe 's:<li>lorem.*?</li>::'
```