# Replacing string within a search string in sed

Tags: regex, string, replace, sed

I have a .sql dump with html content in it. I want to remove a title="...." from `<img...>` strings.
Tricky part is that these title="....." als appears in `<href.....>` parts of a line.

To make it more visible I use the following strings in a 2 line file:

```
A B C D B C A B C
Y B C D B C Y B C
```

The B reprecents the `title="...."` part  and  `A....C` is the `<img....>` part

The resulting file should look like

```
A C D B C A C
Y B C D B C Y B C
```

Only the `B` should be removed within `A...C` and the seccond line should be untouched

I'm using sed because I know this best but if somebody knows a better way I'm interested to know.

Till now I've used the following command

```
cat file |sed '/A/ s/B/X/g'
```

Problem is it also replaces the `B` within `D...C`

```
A C D C A C
Y B C D B C Y B C
```

Any ideas would be appriciated.

regards,

Arjan

PS: Real life example, just one line:

```
nbsp;</p><p> <img src="images/vlaggen/dene_vlag.png" border="0" alt="Vlag van Denemarken" title="REMOVE THIS TITLE" width="75" height="50" align="left" />  <a href="images/hov.png" target="_blank" title="DONT REMOVE THIS TITLE"><img src="images/small.png" border="0" alt="Kaart van Denemarken" title="REMOVE THIS TITLE" align="right" /></a>   <br /><br /> </p><p>&nbsp;</p><h1>Title of page</h1>
```

Comment: One line solution :-  write custom parser (search for pattern and remove subsequent string)

Comment: I'm afraid that unless you post an example, you'll receive a response like `sed 's/A B C/A C/g' file` for your example.

Comment: That's true. I'm aware of that. To have a real life example this is an example line with real data. Be aware the title="...." could be in other places and in other number of appearences in a line. I added an real example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want here is a non-greedy regex, something which sed doesn't support. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) provides a potential solution. I've not tested this, but perhaps something along the following lines will help:

```
perl -pe 's|<img(.*?)title=".*?"(.*?)>|<img\1\2>|g'
```

It's early where I am, but the gist of that is "find the img tags, capture everything that isn't a title attribute, and substitute it at the end.

Comment: It's perfect !!! That does exactly what I want. I will scan thru the rest of the file, but it looks like it is functioning very well. I realy need to dive into perl a bit more, it's very powerfull. You saved my day !!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure sure whether I got the problem right...  but I think you need back-references, try something like this:

```
sed 's/\(A\) B \(C\)/\1 \2/g'
```

result:

A C D B C A C

Y B C D B C Y B C