# SED: Use of character as variable in repeat remove code

Tags: sed

I have a need to use a number contained in each line of a text file as a variable in a repeat remove task on that line.

Specifically, per line;
(1) The column position of the START of the number to be selected is known, but not the end. i.e it can be of any digit length, BUT is ended with a space.
(2) Take this number and use it in a repeat remove task across the whole line. I would like to remove ALL text between foo and bar, similar to **foo.*bar** the number of times given in (1). foo and bar are repeated in pairs (foo first) the number of times in (1), and can be different per line.

Does anyone know how to do this with SED please. Keen, through SED, to get a way to control **sed -i 's/foo.*bar//g'** type examples I keep seeing, which removes ALL text from the first foo to the last bar, inclusive. We need all text between foo and bar, for every foo bar that appears.

UPDATE: Consider a file, example.txt

```
someText 1 foo someOtherText bar someOtherOtherText

someText 2 foo someOtherDiffText bar x x x foo text bar
```

We need to return;

```
someText 

someText x x x
```

The numbers tell us how many time the pairing foo-bar, with text between it, appears, and range from 1 to 100s

Kind Regards

HS

Comment: try `'s/foo.*?bar//g'` . Your rules are  unclear for me. Could you explain that with an example?

Answer (score 0):

[Sed lacks non-greedy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed), but try Perl:

```
perl -pe 's|foo .*? bar||g' file.txt
```