# Using sed to replace a possibly ambiguous substring

Tags: regex, sed

I have been using `sed` to strip CVS keywords from many, many files but I have encountered a case where multiple CVS keywords appear on the same line, for which a I do not have an adequate solution. For example, suppose the following line existed in a file:

```
$Revision: 1.2 $  $Date: 2015/01/06 17:14:53 $
```

Now I want the result to like:

```
$Revision$  $Date$
```

However, the sed command I have been using:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(\$Revision:\).*\( \$\)/\$Revision\$/'
```

finds the outter most fit to the search, which strips the Date keyword:

```
$Revision$
```

Without any assumptions on order (Revision and Date might be flipped) nor any assumptions of their line placement (cant assume beginning or end of line), how can I strip the keywords independently?

Comment: You need non-greedy regexes which are in Perl, but probably not in sed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem you stumbled upon is the fact that `sed` matches *greedy*, meaning:

```
sed 's/a.*a/b/' <<< 'a_a_a'
```

will produce

```
b
```

and not(!)

```
b_a
```

In many regular expression engines you can use something like `a.*?a` to perform a *none greedy* match, but in sed's regular expressions lanaguage (basic or extended POSIX regular expressions) you need to use:

```
sed 's/a[^a]*a/\b/' <<< 'a_a_a'
```

---

Based on that, you can use the following `sed` commands:

```
sed -r 's/(\$Revision):[^$]+\$/\1$/' input.file
```

**Note:** Check always if it is working before you use the `-i` option.

---

If you want a list of tags getting replaced, use

```
sed -r 's/\$(Revision|Date|AndSoOn):[^$]+\$/$\1$/g' input.file
```

---

If you are about to apply it to all CVS tags, use:

```
sed -r 's/(\$[^:]+):[^$]+\$/\1$/g' input.file
```

Comment: You can improve sed command for the _all CVS tags_ with `sed -r 's/(\$[^:]+):[^$]+/\1/g' input.file`

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish Actually it should be: `sed -r 's/(\$[^:]+):[^$]+\$/\1\$/g' file` :) .. But will add that!

Comment: Can you explain why `\$` is required after `[^$]+`?

Comment: Because it might otherwise produce false matches like `$Revision: foobar` < --- without the closing `$`. I mean it is source code! we should be careful, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/^$Revision/{s/:[^$]*\$/$/g}' file
```

Output:

```
$Revision$  $Date$
```