# Regular expression in sed (gnuwin32 in cmd.exe)

Tags: regex, sed, expression

I would like to erase or replace in data exactly this: ": 20.08.2015 "

sample of data:

```
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:26 :  ''    1  0 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    1  0 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    1  0 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    1  0 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:27 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:30 :  ''    1  0 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:30 :  ''    0  1 
: 20.08.2015 02:39:31 :  ''    1  0
```

after replace it should be:

```
02:39:26 :  ''    0  1
02:39:26 :  ''    0  1
02:39:26 :  ''    0  1
02:39:26 :  ''    0  1
02:39:26 :  ''    0  1
02:39:26 :  ''    1  0
02:39:27 :  ''    1  0
02:39:27 :  ''    1  0
02:39:27 :  ''    0  1
02:39:27 :  ''    1  0
02:39:27 :  ''    0  1
02:39:27 :  ''    0  1
02:39:30 :  ''    1  0
```

In pspad I can do it with expression "^(.*?).([0-9]+? )" but in cmd it doesn't work.

I added escape char in front of special characters.

My try is: "`sed -i "s/(.*?).([0-9]\+?\ )//g`" file.log

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/^: 20\.08\.2015 //' file.log
```

not sure `-i` works in gnuwin (normaly GNU is ok)

if the date value is not exactly 20.08.2015 but in same format

```
sed -i 's/^: [0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.[12][09][0-9]\{2\} //' file.log
```

don't forget that `.` is *any char* and not *dot* so escape it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/: [0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{4\} //' file.log
```

The problem in your expression is the lazy matching (`+?`) on your digits...this is [not supported by `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103177/703229).

Answer (score 0):

so, guys u were close, this works for me:

```
sed -i "s/: [0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.[12][09][0-9]\{2\} //g" file.log
```

thank you!