# Find and replace - bash

Tags: bash

I want to replace `fw["` with `fw.`.

I have tried couple of `sed` commands, but couldn't solve the issue.

I tried `cut` command, `tr` and `sed` commands. But since the characters I like to replace are special characters, I get lot of errors.

This is my input:

```
endpoint.os.version="Windows 10"
endpoint.fw["MSWindowsFW"].version="10.0"
endpoint.av["AlwilAV"].version="11.1.2253"
endpoint.os.hotfix["KB3116278"]="true"
```

This is the output I want:

```
endpoint.os.version="Windows 10"
endpoint.fw.MSWindowsFW.version="10.0"
endpoint.av["AlwilAV"].version="11.1.2253"
endpoint.os.hotfix["KB3116278"]="true"
```

Can you help me to write such a transform?

Comment: What kind of input do you work with? A stream? One or multiple files? A Variable? Short hint: escape (ie.: `echo 'fw["' | tr -d '["'`).

Comment: Hi! it is just one file has 4 lines (inputs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `file.txt`:

```
endpoint.os.version="Windows 10"
endpoint.fw["MSWindowsFW"].version="10.0"
endpoint.av["AlwilAV"].version="11.1.2253"
endpoint.os.hotfix["KB3116278"]="true"
```

As [POSIX regular expressions are greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103177/248390), you could do it like this with Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/fw\["(.*?)"\]/fw.\1/g' file.txt
```

Or in pure sed:

```
sed 's/fw\["\([^"]*\)"\]/fw.\1/g' file.txt
```

Note: I recommend you to used https://regex101.com/ or https://www.debuggex.com/ to test, visualize and understand what your regular expression is doing.

Otherwise for your problem, you just had to avoid the "special characters" to be interpreted by your shell; in my examples I put them between single quotes but you could have escaped them (ie: `tr -d \[\"` is equivalent to `tr -d '["'`).

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. It solves my problem, but it replaces all [" with ".". I very specifically like to replace fw[" with fw. and leave the rest as it is

Comment: Edited... does it fit your need now?

Comment: Indeed. I got what I need. Thank you for quicker and best response.