# Regex in sed to replace substrings

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having some trouble getting the right output here.

I have this sample text

```
test {
  abc: rem(1px);
  def: rem(2px) rem(3px);
}
```

And this current sed command

```
sed -lE "s/rem\((.*)\)/\1/g" test.css
```

But my output looks like this

```
test {
  abc: 1px;
  def: 2px) rem(3px;
}
```

And my goal is this

```
test {
  abc: 1px;
  def: 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed (second answer) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
sed -lE "s/rem\(([^()]*)\)/\1/g" test.css
```

to remove all individual `rem()`s. The `[^()]` bracket expression (if we use POSIX terminology) matches any character but `(` and `)`.

*Pattern details*:

- `rem\(` - match a literal `rem(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 matching 0 or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

The `\1` restores the captured text in the resulting string after replacement.