# Get first set of 8 numbers only with Sed

Tags: regex, parsing, sed

I have some code I'm using with Windows and SED to give me the first set of eight characters in a file name that keeps giving me the second set only that I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**My Code:**

```
echo JiggySauce_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt | sed -r "s/.*_([0-9]*)_.*/\1/g"
```

**Addition Example *(so regex per underbar delimiters won't always work)*:**

```
echo JiggySauce_Mustard_Mayo_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt | sed -r "s/.*_([0-9]*)_.*/\1/g"
```

**I keep getting this wrong result (at least not what I need):**

```
21325005
```

**My expected result:**

```
20161208
```

**I could even live with *(preferrably not but could work with that I suppose)*:**

```
20161208_21325005
```

Please help me with this if you have an answer as I'm at a standstill looking dumb and stumped over here like UHHH....

Comment: Probably related to sed pattern matching being greedy. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed

Comment: I see that you are interested in a `sed` solution, specifically, but it might still be of interest that `grep -o` would do nicely.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Add an answer for Grep if you have one that works, I can use Grep as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With GNU sed:**

```
echo JiggySauce_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt | sed -r 's/^[^_]*_([^_]*).*/\1/'
```

**Output:**

```
20161208
```

---

**Post Initial Answer Update:**

> I suggest: `sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]{8}).*/\1/'`
>   [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)

**Output:**

```
20161208
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: This works for my one example but I forgot to mention that the file names may have other name parts with additional underbars though so for example I also have `JiggySauce_Mustard_Mayo_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt` where that wouldn't work. I give you plus one regardless but will update my question with this detail I was missing. I look forward to a working answer from you still if you have one... I will glady accept if you do... Thank you much regardless though.

Comment: I suggest: `sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]{8}).*/\1/'`

Comment: That is what I needed... Thank you.... Please update your answer with this when you get a chance... this is the answer I need. I will keep an eye on it an accept once you update your answer to include that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
echo JiggySauce_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | head -1
```

or

```
echo JiggySauce_20161208_21325005_Meat.txt | tr '_' '\n' | grep -m1 -Eo '[0-9]+'
```