# Bash output remove text between two characters

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have the output of a bash command:

```
8.8.8.8#53 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A
```

I would like to add to the bash command a regex expression to remove from the # to the next space, for the desired output of:

```
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A
```

I have tried piping the output to **`sed 's/#.*?\s//'`** (which in theory would also remove the trailing space, but this is acceptable), but output remains the same as the original.

Any suggestion on how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think sed supports the non-greedy operator `?`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103149)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` as following.

```
sed 's/#[^ ]*//'
```

Remove `#` followed by everything which is non-space until first space seen.

Or in `bash` with same:

```
str='8.8.8.8#53 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A'
echo "${str//#+([^ ])/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed`, `awk`, or any other tooling that isn't the shell's own built-in string operations.

```
shopt -s extglob

s='8.8.8.8#53 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A'
s_pruned="${s//#+([[:digit:]])/}"
echo "$s_pruned"
```

...properly emits:

```
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try following sed too once.

```
sed 's/\([^#]*\)\([^a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \3/g'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash itself has sed quality regex capability built in (if a bit more wordy...)

You can do:

```
$ txt="8.8.8.8#53 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A"
$ [[ $txt =~ ^([^#]+)#[^[:space:]]+(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A
```

Answer (score 0):

sed don't support the "non greedy" operator.

But I think you can dot this easily. doing

```
echo "8.8.8.8#53 google-public-dns-a.google.com. A" |sed 's/#\w*//'
```