# How to extract first sentence of a file in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to extract the first sentence of a file in bash. I used the following command:

```
sed 's/(\?|\.|!).*//' filename
```

However, it does not work. What is wrong with my regex?

If I have the following sentence in the file: `Stack overflow is the best? I am also the best.`, the output needs to be `Stack overflow is the best?`

Note: the question mark needs to be there at the end. Also the sentence may end with full stop / question mark / exclamation mark.

Edit: The sentence might contain words like `Mr.` etc

Comment: It's a complicated issue, as it depends on the language used. Think of `Mr. Stack overflow is the best.` A naive solution will stop at `Mr.`.

Comment: Maybe he knows much about input. @Pawamoy

Comment: No, I would prefer a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/([.*\?]|[.*\.]|[.*!]).*/\1/' file
              ^       ^     ^   ^  ^
              |_______|_____|___|__|_> Any symbols before first `?` **OR**
                      |_____|___|__|_> Any symbols before first `.` **OR**
                            |___|__|_> Any symbols before first `!`
                                |__|_> Any symbols
                                   |_> Print all found symbols in first pair of brackets
```

My solution will find:

"`(`Any symbols before first `?` found *or* Any symbols before first `.` found *or* Any symbols before first `!` found `)`, any symbols after that. --> print found in brackets symbols".

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong in my solution?

Comment: @rjmessibarca in your solution sed use "base" regex, not extened (in my case, it's `-r` key). Your sed just can't find matches so it do nothing. Also if you add `-r` key in your solution, It will just delete all the symbols after first `?`, or after first `!`, or after first `.`, not printing all the symbols before it.

Comment: @rjmessibarca nope

Comment: An explanation would help a lot.

Comment: My solution will find: `(`"Any symbols before first `?` found or Any symbols before first `.` found or Any symbols before firts `!`found`)`, any symbols after that. --> print found in brackets symbols". Your solution will: "Find **all** symbols, with `?` at the **end** of string, or with `.` at the end of string, or `!` at the end of string, print found match in brackets.

Comment: @ViktorKhilin is preferable to make an edit in your post with this explanation than explain in comments. It's also more readable.

Comment: @ViktorKhilin that's the hard way ;)

Comment: I don't think the bracket expressions do what you think they do. What is the idea of `[.*\?]`? This matches any one character of `.`, `*`, ``\`` or `?`. And alternation between character classes doesn't make sense either. The whole expression `([.*\?]|[.*\.]|[.*!])` is equivalent to `[.*\?!]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not matching the beginning of the line. My solution is:

`^.*?[.?!]`

Which means:

- ^ : The match must be at the beginning of the line
- .*? : any number of characters (greedy, aka as less as possible)
- [.?!]] : match one of the chars inside []

Working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/JY8d2D/2)

Note that solution its working for python. I think [there are no greedy searches with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: It's `sed`, `([.?!]).*`

Comment: ```$ cat filename 
Stack overflow is the best? I am also the best.
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC Stackoverflow]$ sed '^.*?[.?!]' filename
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'``` You sure it works? (off.: how can I place line break in comments? :( )

Comment: @ViktorKhilin You can't. PS: Thanks for pointing. I've tried the solution and didn't work with sed. Greedy searches are not available.

Answer (score 1):

If your input file consists of just one line, you can use

```
$ grep -o '^[^.!?]*[.!?]' <<< 'Stack overflow is the best? I am also the best.'
Stack overflow is the best?
```

If there are multiple lines and your first sentence might be across multiple lines, you can use `-z` with GNU grep to treat the file as a single line:

```
$ grep -zo '^[^.!?]*[.!?]' <<< $'Stack overflow\nis the best? I am also the best.'
Stack overflow
is the best?
```

The regex consists of these components:

- `^` anchor to start of line
- `[^.!?]*` zero or more characters other than `.`, `!` or `?`
- `[.!?]` on of `.`, `!` or `?`

Answer (score 0):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown example then following `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed 's/[\?\.\!].*/\?/'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Stack overflow is the best?
```

Comment: Sentences could be finished with comma or `!`, not only `?` as I understood.

Comment: @ViktorKhilin, OP has not mentioned it and I had mentioned that as per shown sample only this code is.

Comment: I think it was just an example, but I like your solution for the single defined symbol in the end.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Although, I have not downvoted. But, the sentence can end with ! or . or ?