# Regex failed in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Input:

```
get \tag-start Snooby ~p snoopy \tag-end please
```

Output: `Snooby` (after the tag and before ~p; non-greedy capture because some sentences contain several tags)

```
echo 'get \tag-start Snooby ~p snoopy \tag-end please' | sed 's/.*tag-start \(.*?\) ~p.*/\1/'
```

I don't know where goes wrong but this regex doesn't work to extract info in this case.

Comment: If you use `.*` instead of `.*?` it will work in this case. Probably, you can use `sed 's/.*tag-start \([^~]*\) ~p.*/\1/'` if the expected value does not contain `~`.

Comment: Yes, it works in this case to get rid of non-greedy, thanks a lot!

Comment: You may accept Sundeep's answer then, but this is a dupe anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Non-greedy is not supported by most `sed` implementations (I vaguely remember one implementation allowing PCRE)

As mentioned by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) in comments, either of these would work for given case

```
$ sed 's/.*tag-start \(.*\) ~p.*/\1/' ip.txt
Snooby
$ sed 's/.*tag-start \([^~]*\) ~p.*/\1/' ip.txt
Snooby
```

As `linux` is tagged, you might have `GNU grep` with PCRE, in which case you can use non-greedy regex as needed

```
$ grep -oP 'tag-start \K.*?(?= ~p)' ip.txt
Snooby
```

Comment: No sed supports PCREs (presumably because the associated regexp engine is very inefficient - see https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) and though grep has `-P` the providers warn us in the man page that it is "highly experimental" and users have reported core dumps when using it.

Comment: the one remembered was [ssed](https://launchpad.net/ssed/) - it has PCRE features... yeah `grep -P` is mentioned as experimental but that's been in man page for long time, I've never had any issues with it.. there are significantly more outstanding issues with normal grep than PCRE(https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=grep)

Comment: nice link for regex comparison, will go through sometime.. PCRE is often better in speed performance with back-references.. for ex `([a-z]..)\1` .. as it supports plenty of features compared to ERE, it certainly would be inefficient in many cases..

Answer (score -1):

Try this `sed`:

```
echo "get \tag-start Snooby ~p snoopy \tag-end please" |sed 's/.*tag-start \(.*\) ~p.*/\1/'
```

Output:

`Snooby`

Comment: What's the reason for DOWNVOTE?