# I have to replace a string present between two strings using 'sed' command in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have to replace a string present between two strings using `sed` command in Unix.

My Input is :

```
Apple'Mangoabcd'Orange'Mangoxyz'Lemon'
```

The command I used is

```
sed 's/Mango.*'"'"'/+XXXX'"'"'/'
```

My desired Output is

```
Apple'XXXX'Orange'XXXX'Lemon'
```

The output I get is

```
Apple'XXXX'
```

I want to replace `'Mango+freetext'` with `'XXXX'` in all the places.

Comment: Try `sed "s/Mango[^']*/XXXX/"`, or probably `sed "s/'Mango[^']*/'XXXX/"` will be more precise if `Mango` should be preceded with `'`

Comment: Sorry. I missed few things. I have to replace free texts present between 'Mango' and first instance of  '  .    So, My input will be some thing like this  "Input = Apple'Mangoabcd'Orange'

Comment: So, `sed "s/\(Mango\)[^']*/\1'XXXX/"`? Or just `sed "s/Mango[^']*/XXXX/"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: I think all you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103159/3832970). There are other helpful answers there, too.

Comment: Use `sed "s/Mango[^']*/XXXX/g"`

Comment: @Wiktor, Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you just want to replace `Mango` and you know it is `Mango`, then you just do

   ```
   sed 's/Mango/XXXX/g'
   ```
2. If you want to replace `Mango<freetext>` where the freetext does not contain a single quote `'`, then you do :

   ```
   sed "s/'Mango[^']*/'XXXX/g"
   ```

   we added the extra quote before `Mango` to make sure we exclude strings such as `'SquashedMangoJuice'`
3. If you want to replace the string between the words `Apple` and `Orange`, then you have to do it a bit different :

   ```
   sed "s/Apple'[^']*'Orange/Apple'XXXX'Orange/g"
   ```

   or using back-references

   ```
   sed "s/\(Apple'\)[^']*\('Orange\)/\1XXXX\2/g"
   ```

The reason why your original command is failing is that `sed` is greedy. What I mean is that the combination `.*'` will pick everything until the last quote. That is, it will represent `Mango'Orange'`. The culprit is the last quote after `Orange`. Above, we fixed this by replacing your `.` with `[^']`. This means all characters except the quote `'`.

Comment: Sorry. I missed few things. I have to replace free texts present between 'Mango' and first instance of ' . So, My input will be some thing like this "Input = Apple'Mangoabcd'Orange'

Comment: @Sathya, could you please update your original question to represent this. Especially the given input and expected output. Also clearly state if the Apples and Oranges have anything to do with the replacement (if it is a condition or not) or if `Pear'Mango_foobar'Banana'` should also be replaced. Also could the string that need to be replaced contain a quote.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have multiple occurrence of the string which I am replacing in my Input.

Comment: Hi, I tried the 2nd option. but it is replacing only the first instance. so my output is coming as " Apple'XXXX'Orange'Mangoabcd'Lemon' " instead of "  Apple'XXXX'Orange'XXXX'Lemon' "

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 2nd Command perfectly suits my requirement :-)

Comment: @Sathya you are welcome. Don't forget [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)