# s/// returns out of place newline

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I'm trying to use Perl to reorder the content of an md5 file. For each line, I want the filename without the path then the hash. The best command I've come up with is:

```
$ perl -pe 's|^([[:alnum:]]+).*?([^/]+)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5
```

The input file (`DCIM.md5`) is produced by `md5sum` on Linux. It looks like this:

```
e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2  ./Path1/IMG_20150201_160548.jpg
01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939  ./Path 2/IMG_20150204_190528.jpg
afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101  ./Path3/Path 4/IMG_20151011_193008.jpg
```

1. The hash is matched by the first group `([[:alnum:]]+)` in the
   regular expression.
2. Then the spaces and the path to the file are
   matched by `.*?`.
3. Then the filename is matched by `([^/]+)`.
4. The expression is enclosed with `^` (apparently non-necessary here) 
   and `$`. Without the `$`, the expression does not output what I expect.
5. I use `|` rather than `/` as a separator to avoid escaping it in file paths.

That command returns:

```
IMG_20150201_160548.jpg
 e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2IMG_20150204_190528.jpg
 01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939IMG_20151011_193008.jpg
 afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101IMG_20151011_195133.jpg
```

The matching is correct, the output sequence is correct (filename without path then hash) but the spacing is not: there's a newline after the filename. I expect it after the hash, like this:

```
IMG_20150201_160548.jpg e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2
IMG_20150204_190528.jpg 01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939
IMG_20151011_193008.jpg afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101
```

It seems to me that my command outputs the newline character, but I don't know how to change this behavior.
Or possibly the problem comes from the shell, not the command?

Finally, some version information:

```
$ perl -version
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
(with 69 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: `[^/]`will match non slash (including newlines). Maybe try `[^\n/]`

Comment: If you're matching a hex string then it would be better to use `[[:xdigit:]]` rather than `[[:alnum:]]`. Alternatively, the Unicode property `\p{Hex}` is more concise and more modern.

Comment: I think your work ("your" referring to the OP's) on solving this problem, especially your strategy for getting the filename, is ingenious! I will combine it with the answers given. It will be better than my usual: `s|^.*/(.*)$|$1|` approach (which must be used with the `-l` switch, as discussed by @Shawn, as well as the `-p` switch you've used). It'll be `perl -lpe 's|([^/])$|$1|` for me to find filenames being the last entry on a line. I love it!

Comment: One other suggestion: Use `[:xdigit:]` instead of `[:alnum:]`, to help with the (admittedly unlikely) case of getting a line that doesn't start with a valid hash.

Comment: @ChrisCharley, it's very correct that the `[^/]` will match newlines. Am I correct in surmising that it's actually the plus after, i.e. `<code>` [^/] **+** `</code>`, that causes this behavior to be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[^/]+` matches newlines, so the ones in your input are part of `$2`, which gets put first in your transformed `$_` (And there's no newline in `$1` so there's no newline at the end of `$_`...)

Solution: Read up on the `-l` option from [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). In particular:

> -l[octnum]
>   enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/ .

Comment: So, basically, you're saying that all @raph82 was missing was an `-l` flag to go along with the `-pe`, then the goal would be accomplished? It worked for me when I tried it. `$ perl -lpe 's|^([[:alnum:]]+).*?([^/]+)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5` gave me the desired output.

Comment: @bballdave025 Yup. No need to muck with the regular expression and make it even more cryptic and linenoisey. Even if it is just for a one-liner.

Comment: I like that approach. Good 'on ya.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution, which uses lots of concepts from other answers, and comments ...

```
$ perl -pe 's|(\p{hex}+).*?([^/]+?)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5
```

... and explanation.

After investigating all the answers and trying to figure them out, I've decided that the base of the problem is that the `[^/]+` is **greedy**. Its greediness causes it to capture the newline; it ignores the `$` anchor.

This was hard for me to figure out, since I did a lot of parsing using `sed` before using Perl, and even a greedy wildcard won't capture a newline in `sed`. Hopefully this post will help those who (being used to `sed` as I am) are also wondering (as I did) why the `$` isn't acting "as I expect it to."

We can see the "greedy" issue by trying what I'll post as another, alternate answer.

Write the file:

```
$ cat > DCIM.md5<<EOF
> e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2  ./Path1/IMG_20150201_160548.jpg
> 01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939  ./Path 2/IMG_20150204_190528.jpg
> afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101  ./Path3/Path 4/IMG_20151011_193008.jpg
> EOF
```

Get rid of the greedy `[^/]+` by changing it to `[^/]+?`. Parse.

```
$ perl -pe 's|([[:alnum:]]+).*?([^/]+?)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5
IMG_20150201_160548.jpg e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2
IMG_20150204_190528.jpg 01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939
IMG_20151011_193008.jpg afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101
```

Desired output accomplished.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52347408/6505499), by @Shawn,

```
$ perl -lpe 's|^([[:alnum:]]+).*?([^/]+)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5
```

basically changes the `$` anchor so as to behave the way a `sed` person would expect it to.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52347417/6505499) by @CrafterKolyan takes care of the greedy `[^/]` capturing the newline by saying you can't have a forward-slash *or* a newline. This answer still needs the `$` anchor to prevent the following situation

1) `.*` captures the empty string (**0** or more of any character)

2) `[^/\n]+` captures   `.` .

The answer by @Borodin takes a quite different approach, but it's a great concept.

@Borodin, in addition, made a great [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347330/s-returns-out-of-place-newline/52347408?noredirect=1#comment91642134_52347330) that allows a more-precise/more-exact version of this answer, which is the version I put at the top of this post.

Finally, if one wants to follow the [Perl programming model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), here's another alternative.

```
$ perl -pe 's|([[:xdigit:]]+).*?([^/]+?)(\n\|\Z)|$2 $1$3|' DCIM.md5
```

---

P.S. Because `sed` isn't quite like `perl` ([no non-greedy wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103177/6505499),) here's a `sed` example that shows the behavior I discuss.

```
$ sed 's|^\([[:alnum:]]\+\).*/\([^/]\+\)$|\2 \1|' DCIM.md5
```

This is basically a "direct translation" of the `perl` expression *except* for the extra `'/'` before the `[^/]` stuff. I hope it will help those comparing `sed` and `perl`.

Answer (score 2):

use `[^/\n]` instead of `[^/]`:

`perl -pe 's|^([[:alnum:]]+).*?([^/\n]+)$|$2 $1|' DCIM.md5`

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It gives precisely the output desired by the OP. In addition, it gives executable code, which is always good to have in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a substitution leaves you having to write a regex pattern that matches everything you *don't* want as well as everything you do. It's usually much better to match just the parts you need and build another string from them

Like this

```perl
for ( <> ) {
    die unless m< (\w++) .*? ([^/\s]+) \s* \z >x;
    print "$2 $1\n";
}
```

or if you *must* have a one-liner

```
perl -ne 'die unless m< (\w++) .*? ([^/\s]+) \s*\z >x; print "$2 $1\n";' myfile.md5
```

#### output

```
IMG_20150201_160548.jpg e26ff03dc1bac80226e200c0c63d17a2
IMG_20150204_190528.jpg 01f92572e4c6f2ea42bd904497e4f939
IMG_20151011_193008.jpg afce027c977944188b4f97c5dd1bd101
```