# Extract UUID of /dev/nvme0 device with sed

Tags: sed

when I'm configuring grub2 to unlock an LVM root (`rd.luks.name=UUID=cryptroot`) I usually just `blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3 >> uuid`, edit the text and delete all the data that isn't the UUID, and then `:r uuid` to insert it to the grub config in vim. I know there *has* to be an easier way to do this with `sed` but so far the closest I've gotten is as follows:

```
➜  ~ blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="2276de2b-9370-4577-90ea-3b0191ebea4e" 
TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="b7a643ce-8bca-418f-a631-b0fc8648432c"

➜  ~ blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3 | sed 's/.*UUID="\(.*\)" .*/\1/'        
2276de2b-9370-4577-90ea-3b0191ebea4e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS
```

Anyone have any idea what I could add to the sed arguments to get rid of everything after the end of the UUID including that quotation mark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed)

Comment: `blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3 | sed -E 's/.*UUID="([^"]*)".*"/\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

or

```
lsblk -n -o UUID /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

Output:

```
2276de2b-9370-4577-90ea-3b0191ebea4e
```

---

See: `man blkid`

Comment: Damn I suck. Thank you so much, both for the solution and reminding me to always check the manual