# Unix shell scripting- how do I use the output of href in my shellscript

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Unix shell scripting- how do I use the output of href in my shellscript. I need the link of a path alone to be as an output in my script. except for the email option. Please suggest me with other options.
when I use the echo command the entire line is displayed, while I need only the link (Go)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '<a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com">Go</a>'
```

Comment: could you be more specific in your question? what is your input for shell script? do you need to extract html links from it?

Comment: what is the problem to change you long line with "Go"? Do you need your link to be clickable in linux console?

Comment: Yes. i actually need a path and I need it clickable

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to extract "Go" from `<a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com">Go</a>`. Is this correct ? If so, you can use perl which probably have the most poweful regexes around `echo '<a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com">Go</a>'  | perl  -pe 's|<a href.+>(.+)</a>|\1|'` (thanks to [this question/reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed).

Comment: I need the link as a  output in my shell script.. in this case i would need 'Go' which redirects me to the link.